# Make an alphabet searchlight!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

Inspired by [a bug](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSM5I7FIq1izujwjMydVA8RKyy/SyLI1M7XOsrE0tM7S1tbUKra1zbIvKMrMK0nTUNMqBgpZQXlKCkqa1gWlJcUaSkBGbe3/3MTMPA2gIRpKUZER4WGhIcFBgQH@fr4@3l6eHu5uri7OTo4glf8B) in a solution to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141372/61563), your challenge is to produce this exact text:

```
                         ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                        YXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                       XWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                      WVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                     VUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                    UTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                   TSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                  SRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                 RQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
                QPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
               PONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
              ONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
             NMLKJIHGFEDCBA
            MLKJIHGFEDCBA
           LKJIHGFEDCBA
          KJIHGFEDCBA
         JIHGFEDCBA
        IHGFEDCBA
       HGFEDCBA
      GFEDCBA
     FEDCBA
    EDCBA
   DCBA
  CBA
 BA
A
```

- The first line will have 25 spaces, then the alphabet backwards starting from the 26th letter (`ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`), then a newline.
- The second line will have 24 spaces, then the alphabet backwards starting from the 25th letter (`YXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`), then a newline.
- ...
- The last (26th) line will have no spaces, then the alphabet backwards starting from the 1st letter (`A`), then a newline.

Additional rules:

- Your program may use any allowed output methods.
- One trailing newline and/or one leading newline is allowed.
- There must be one newline between lines containing the letters, no more.
- The letters must be all uppercase.

As with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest submission wins. Good luck!

Leaderboard:

```js
var QUESTION_ID=141725,OVERRIDE_USER=61563;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: To me it looks like the light cast by the bat-signal

Comment: [Closely Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140198/semi-diagonal-alphabet).

Comment: Can each line have an extra space in front of it?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino no.

Comment: Could each line have trailing spaces after the last letter?

Comment: @miles yes, that's fine.

Comment: Can I add a [leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet) please, or @MDXF if you would like the override could you add it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

#### Code:

```
₂žp.s1Λ
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UVPT0X0FesWG52b//w8A)

#### Explanation

```
 žp.s      # Get the suffixes of ZYX...CBA
      Λ    # Using the canvas mode, print the
₂          # first 26 elements of the array
     1     # into the upper-right direction
```

Comment: I need to learn how asciicanvas work :-)

Comment: @MDXF IMO, that's a really dumb rule

Comment: Hmm... I guess I'll remove the rule, then. [tag:status-completed]

Comment: I feel like you should have asked what [Miles has now asked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141725/make-an-alphabet-searchlight#comment347438_141725) since the question does state "produce this exact text".

Comment: @scottinet yeah there isn't any documentation yet, except for some answers on challenges :p.

Comment: I might propose a PR documenting that feature when I find the time. Seems to be a good way to learn a bit of python from a well-written, easy-to-read code

Comment: Why does `žp` exist when `Au` is golden? ***BADUM*** *tissss*

Comment: @scottinet Yeah, documentation is not the strongest point of 05AB1E. If you could do that, that would be awesome!

Comment: Using 05AB1E, create a file documenting all of it's features, shortes code wins :P

Comment: @Christian at one point an empty program printed this haha. [Edit, it still does xD.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/Q8EAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @scottinet Only see this answer now (upvoted btw, nice answer!), but a few months back I created [an explanation on how to use the 05AB1E Canvas on the 05AB1E tip page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210). :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, I have already upvoted it a while ago :). Thank you for doing that, as well as for the elaborate explanation of the compression techniques!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn `žp` is `ZYX...CBA` wile `Au` is `ABC...XYZ`. Although in this case, `žp.s` could also be `Auηí` for the same byte-count.

Answer (score 22):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>67</s> 55 bytes

```r
for(i in 26:1)cat(rep(" ",i-1),LETTERS[i:1],"
",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwcjMylAzObFEoyi1QENJQUknU9dQU8fHNSTENSg4OtPKMFZHiUtJpzi1wFZJSfP/fwA)

Comment: R is beating Python on a string challenge? Nice. +1 for LETTERS

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar it's a very weird challenge; Haskell is beating the tie of PHP and R which are both beating Python... at least Perl is ahead of all of them like you might expect.

Comment: -2 bytes if you change `sep` to `s`.  Functions will autocomplete named arguments if there aren't collisions

Comment: @Punintended that won't work because of the `...` argument; arguments that come before `...` (typically) get partial matched, and those after don't. I believe there are a few exceptions but `cat` isn't one of them

Comment: @Giuseppe I don't see a `...`

Comment: @MilkyWay90 the `...` argument is a special one in R, representing a variadic argument list. `cat` in particular [has the signature](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/base/html/cat.html) `cat(...,file="",sep=" ",fill=FALSE,labels=NULL,append=FALSE)`. Named arguments are typically matched on the shortest unique substring, e.g., the call `parse(t= <arg>)` is equivalent to `parse(text = <arg>)`. See page 44 of the [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) for a bit more information.

Comment: @Giuseppe I see. I don't know how to program in R, so I thought there was an explicit `...`

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
i=26
while i:i-=1;print' '*i+bytearray(range(65+i,64,-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWyIyrPCMzJ1Uh0ypT19bQuqAoM69EXUFdK1M7qbIkNbGoKLFSoygxLz1Vw8xUO1PHzERH11BT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 16):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>13</s>, 11 bytes

```
¬ZAòY>HGpxl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//9CaKMfDmyLtPNwLKnL@/wcA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: ac5a 41f2 593e 4847 7078 6c              .ZA.Y>HGpxl
```

Written from my phone :P.

```
¬ZA         " Insert the alphabet backwards
   ò        " Recursively:
    Y       "   Yank this current line
     >H     "   Add one space to every line
       G    "   Move to the last line in the buffer
        p   "   Paste the line we yanked
         x  "   Delete one character
          l "   Move one character to the right, which will throw an error on 
            "   the last time through, breaking the loop
```

Comment: I do these on my phone too, +1

Answer (score 13):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes

```powershell
25..0|%{' '*$_+-join[char[]]((65+$_)..65)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/38hUT8@gRrVaXUFdSyVeWzcrPzMvOjkjsSg6NlZDw8xUWyVeU0/PzFSz9v9/AA)

#### Explanation:

```powershell
25..0|%{                                 } # Loop from 25 to 0
                             (65+$_)..65   # Construct a range of the specific ASCII codes
                    [char[]](           )  # Cast that as a character array
               -join                       # that has been joined together into a string
        ' '*$_+                            # Prepended with the correct amount of spaces
```

Answer (score 11):

## Bash + GNU sed, 60

```bash
printf %s {Z..A}|sed 'h
s/./ /g
G
s/ \n//
:x
p
s/ \S//
tx
d'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1WKE6Sk/PsbamODVFQT2Dq1hfT19BP53LHchSiMnT1@eyquAqAHOCgZySCq4U9f//AQ).

Comment: You can save two bytes by changing `:x` to `:` and `tx` to `t`.

Answer (score 10):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>105</s> 97 bytes

```
/:/\\\\*//#/:Z:Y:X:W:V:U:T:S:R:Q:P:O:N:M:L:K:J:I:H:G:F:E:D:C:B:A//\\*/\/\/_____#
\/ //_/     //*#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu7DoIwAEbh3ado0o3l38@mIuAFQVBQ0qRhIGFg6/un0u/MJ2xzWJcQo5DbZZIVEz@@jAx8eNPT8aKl4UnNgzs3rlSUFFzIOXPiKKXZ7fnEHpyM5GUSKbMx/gE)

#### Explanation

/// only knows one command, `/<pattern>/<substitution>/<text>` replaces all occurrences of `<pattern>` in `<text>` with `<substitution>`. Additionally `\` can be used to escape characters.

Shortened code for simplicity:

```
/:/\\\\*//#/:E:D:C:B:A//\\*/\/\/__#
\/ //_/  //*#
```

The first command `/:/\\\\*/` replaces `:` with `\\*` in the subsequent code. This gives:

```
/#/\\*E\\*D\\*C\\*B\\*A//\\*/\/\/__#
\/ //_/  //*#
```

Then `/#/\\*E\\*D\\*C\\*B\\*A/` replaces `#` with `\*E\*D\*C\*B\*A`:

```
/\\*/\/\/__\*E\*D\*C\*B\*A
\/ //_/  //*\*E\*D\*C\*B\*A
```

Then `/\\*/\/\/__\*E\*D\*C\*B\*A<newline>\/ /` replaces `\*` with `//__*E*D*C*B*A<newline>/`:

```
/_/  //*//__*E*D*C*B*A
/ E//__*E*D*C*B*A
/ D//__*E*D*C*B*A
/ C//__*E*D*C*B*A
/ B//__*E*D*C*B*A
/ A
```

Notice: I had to use `\*` for replacement. Since `*` is also part of the substitution, it would generate an infinite loop if I only replace `*`.

Then command `/_/  /` replaces `_` with spaces, and `/*//` deletes all `*`:

```
EDCBA
/ E//    EDCBA
/ D//    EDCBA
/ C//    EDCBA
/ B//    EDCBA
/ A
```

The next command `/#//` replaces `#` by nothing. Since there is no `#` in the code, it does nothing. This is just here to remove the two leadings `//` from the beginning of the code. This leaves

```
EDCBA
/ E//    EDCBA
/ D//    EDCBA
/ C//    EDCBA
/ B//    EDCBA
/
```

Then the command `/ E//` removes `<space>E`, so this will leave the code

```
    EDCBA
   DCBA
/ D//   DCBA
/ C//   DCBA
/ B//   DCBA
/
```

Similar `/ D//` removes `<space>D`:

```
    EDCBA
   DCBA
  CBA
/ C//  CBA
/ B//  CBA
/
```

`/ C//`:

```
    EDCBA
   DCBA
  CBA
 BA
/ B// BA
/
```

`/ B//`:

```
    EDCBA
   DCBA
  CBA
 BA
A
/
```

And the last command is incomplete, so it does nothing:

```
    EDCBA
   DCBA
  CBA
 BA
A
```

Comment: Same lengths as the C# and brainfuck answers :D

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
f(a:b)=(b>>" ")++a:b++'\n':f b
f x=x
f['Z','Y'..'A']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SpJ01Yjyc5OSUFJU1sbyNXWVo/JU7dKU0jiSlOosK3gSrdNi1aPUtdRj1TX01N3VI/9n5uYmadgq1BQWhJcUqSQ/h8A)

How it works

```
f['Z','Y'..'A']        -- call f with the full backwards alphabet

f(a:b)=                -- let `a` be the first char and `b` the rest. Return
   (b>>" ") ++         -- replace each char in b with a space, followed by
   a:b ++              -- the input string, followed by
   '\n' :              -- a newline, followed by
   f b                 -- a recursive call of `f` with `b`
f x=x                  -- stop on an empty input string
```

Comment: Why doesn't `f['Z'..'A']` work?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: `[a..b]` starts with `a` and collects all the successors (`+1` for integers, next ascii-char for characters, etc.) up to `b`. If `a > b` this is an empty list. However, you can specify also the second value (which can be smaller) from which an increment/decrement is calculated.  `[1,3..8]` -> `[1,3,5,7]`, `[15,10..0]` -> `[15,10,5,0]`, or `['Z','Y'..'A']` which is the backwards uppercase alphabet.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>83</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```js
f=(n=0,p='')=>n<26?f(++n,p+' ')+p+`ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
`.slice(~n):''

o.innerText = f()
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Comment: I had wanted to suggest you an improvement, but then I realized that our approaches are very different. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ThePirateBay No problem!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66</s> 64

```python
i=26
while i:i-=1;print' '*i+'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'[25-i:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWyIyrPCMzJ1Uh0ypT19bQuqAoM69EXUFdK1NbPSoyIjwsNCQ4KDDA38/Xx9vL08PdzdXF2clRPdrIVDfTKvb/fwA)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf - nice first answer!

Comment: Thanks! Figured I'd give it a try instead of just lurking.

Comment: You can remove the space between `print` and `'` for 65 bytes.

Comment: I ported your answer into Pyth, take a look: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141939/63757

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ØAµ⁶ṁḊ;ṚµƤṚY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMdDWx81bnu4s/Hhji7rhztnHdp6bAmQivz/HwA)

```
ØAµ⁶ṁḊ;ṚµƤṚY  Main Link
ØA            "ABC...XYZ"
         Ƥ    For each prefix,
  µ⁶ṁḊ;Ṛµ     Monadic Link
   ⁶          ' '
    ṁ         (with automatic repetition) molded to the shape of
     Ḋ        All but the first letter of the input (repeat - 1)
      ;       With the input          appended to it
       Ṛ                     reversed
           Y  Join on newlines
          Ṛ   Flip upside down
```

-3 bytes thanks to miles

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@nwuFR4zZrrsMzHEMPtx@ecGxJ5P//AA)

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh right cool thanks!

Comment: Yay, another use for the prefix quick. [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMdDWx81bnu4s/Hhji7rhztnHdp6bAmQivz/HwA) since mold will reshape here using the length implicitly.

Comment: @LeakyNun Actually, unfortunately that would make it invalid because there cannot be extra spaces (it would take 2 bytes to fix)

Answer (score 7):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 105 bytes

```
++++++++[>+>+++++++++++>++++>+++<<<<-]>++>++>>++[[->+>+<<]>-[-<<.>>]>[-<<<<.->>>+>]<-[-<+<<+>>>]<<<<.>>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYrRCYBQDAMHKnWCkEVKP1QQRPBDcP6aPhQPUhJ6yzXv53avR5W9BI32w@9AeHIMKhHeJpD0cGAik11UnTKY6IcM@RoYDrPqAQ)

Minified and formatted:

```
++++++++[>+>+++
++++++++>++++>+
++<<<<-]>++>++>
>++[[->+>+<<]>-
[-<<.>>]>[-<<<<
.->>>+>]<-[-<+<
<+>>>]<<<<.>>>]
```

Readable version:

```
[
  pre-initialize the tape with the values 10 90 32 >26<
  C_NEWLINE: 10
  V_ALPHA: 90
  C_SPACE: 32
  V_COUNTER: 26

AS:

  10 = 8 *  1 + 2
  90 = 8 * 11 + 2
  32 = 8 *  4 + 0
  26 = 8 *  3 + 2
]

8 ++++++++ [
  *  1 >+
  * 11 >+++++++++++
  *  4 >++++
  *  3 >+++
<<<<-]
PLUS 2 >++
PLUS 2 >++
PLUS 0 >
PLUS 2 >++

UNTIL V_COUNTER == 0 [
  COPY V_COUNTER to RIGHT and RIGHT_RIGHT
  [->+>+<<]
  TAPE: 10 V_ALPHA 32 >0< V_COUNTER_R V_COUNTER_RR
  V_COUNTER_R SUB 1 TIMES: >-[-
     PRINT C_SPACE <<.
  >>]
  TAPE: 10 V_ALPHA 32 0 >0< V_COUNTER_RR
  V_COUNTER_RR TIMES: >[-
    PRINT V_ALPHA <<<<.
    DECREMENT V_ALPHA -
    INCREMENT V_COUNTER_R >>>+
  >]
  TAPE: 10 V_ALPHA 32 0 V_COUNTER_R(26) >0<
  V_COUNTER_R SUB 1 TIMES: <-[-
    INCREMENT V_COUNTER <+
    INCREMENT V_ALPHA <<+
  >>>]
  PRINT C_NEWLINE <<<<.
>>>]
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 601 bytes

```
one night i camped a bit
throughout all the forest now
the sweet sights
i saw giant things
i saw little small things
here i am
seated around all my trees i saw
i sleep
i sle-e-p
sleep in a cabin
i am sleep-y
i sleep a bit
i awaken in bed
i stand
i walk
i am ready
i saw a vision of a dragon
i am fooled
i know i am
should i f-ight
i f-light
i did f-light
i did a flight
go away,i do imply
i*m afraid
i run
i leave
i flee
i am timid
i*m just a person,not toughie-tough-guy
no,never
i*m waste
i am stupid
a quitter i was
i am stupid
i*m turning around
i do not appreciate camping
i cry
i am crying
no
no
```

Poetic is an esolang I created in 2018 for a class project, and it is a brainfuck derivative in which the lengths of words correspond to brainfuck commands (and the +, -, >, and < commands each have 1-digit arguments).

The fact that only word-length dictates the commands means that I technically could have created a program entirely composed of non-words (i.e. the letter X as many times as needed, with spaces in between words), but I wanted to make an interesting free-verse poem out of it while not adding any unnecessary bytes.

If you want to try it online (which is half the point of the class project in the first place), check out [my online interpreter](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/)!

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: The language was created after the challenge.

Comment: [Answers in languages that postdate the challenge no longer need to be marked non-competing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/46076)

Comment: Hm, then I guess that gives me more motivation to use Poetic as a programming language! Heh.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>53</s> <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

*1 byte removed thanks to [@Sanchises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises)*

```matlab
for k=25:-1:0,disp([blanks(k) 65+k:-1:65])end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Lb9IIdvWyNRK19DKQCcls7hAIzopJzEvu1gjW1PBzFQ7GyRjZhqrmZqX8v8/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
žpDvÐg<ú,¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L4Cl7LDE9JtDu/SObTs/38A)

**Explanations:**

```
žpDvÐg<ú,¦
žp           Push the uppercased alphabet, reversed
  D          Duplicate
   v         For each letter (we just want to loop 26 times, so we use the 
                already pushed alphabet for that purpose)
    Ð        Triplicate
     g<      Length of the string - 1
       ú     Add that number of spaces at the beginning of the string
        ,    Print with newline
         ¦   Remove the 1st element of the remaining copy of the string
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 37 bytes

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @Massa.*

```perl6
say " "x$_,chrs $_+65...65 for 25...0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBSUGpQiVeJzmjqFhBJV7bzFRPT8/MVCEtv0jBCMQ2@P8fAA)

**Explanation:** `25...0` is a range from 25 to 0 (as expected). We iterate over that range, saying (= printing with newline) that many spaces and the string of characters that have ASCII codes (`chrs`) from 65 + that number (`$_+65...65`).

Comment: `25...0`  is the shorter way :-)

Comment: try `say " "x$_,chrs $_+65...65 for 25...0` :-)

Comment: Many thanks! I never knew about that! And the sub form is better too (too bad I made this one from the top of my head). (This is why I like to use Perl 6 for codegolf, I always discover something new.)

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 43 keystrokes

```
:h<_<CR>jjYZZPVgUxjpqqy$-i <Esc>lpl"aDYPD"ap+q25@q
```

You can see it in action in this GIF made using [Lynn's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn) [python script](https://gist.github.com/lynn/5f4f532ae1b87068049a23f7d88581c5)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>19</s> 11 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to ASCII-only.*

```
Ｆ²⁶«Ｐ⮌…α⊕ι↗
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw8hMU6GaSwEIfEtzSjILijLzSjSCUstSi4pTNXzzc1I0EnUUtLUzNTU1Iaryy1I1rEILgjLTM0o0uWr///@vW/ZftzgHAA) Link is to verbose version.

Comment: This maybe? https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw8hcU6GaSwEIfPPLUjWsQguCMtMzSjQhQqU5JZkFRZl5JRpBqWWpRcWpGr75OSkaiToKmZqamly1////1y37r1ucAwA

Comment: Wait noooooo there's leading space

Comment: Son of a... I need to look through every single command and operator Charcoal has. >_> Thanks!

Comment: Fixed https://tio.run/##JcqxCoAgEADQ3a9wvAMdagn6BxehD5C6VBANM5fo26@gN781uLoWl5j3UiVYlz3BoMYJUd5CfsyVWjxqzA0sdaongSlpA6dkRMT/lE4wL4eNPjQUDzPrzvpMLw

Comment: 11 bytes https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw8hMU6GaSwEIfEtzSjILijLzSjSCUstSi4pTNXzzc1I0EnUUtLU1MjWBAKIuvyxVwyq0ICgzPaNEk6v2////umX/dYtzAA

Comment: Um... Is `Mold` even in the docs?

Comment: Yes it is, although it's also called CycleChop, and it's a range overload so I may have forgotten to add it in

Comment: We're still losing to 05ab1e so badly though :(

Comment: Also smart way is longer https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8otSy1qDhVwzexQMPITEdBW0NLQ11BXUchU1NHAS6Zn5OikQiU1NbI1ASD////65b91y3OAQA

Comment: wait [better verbose version :P](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw8hMU6GaSwEIfEtzSjILijLzSjSCUstSi4pTNXzzc1I0EnUUtLUzNTU1Iaryy1I1rEILgjLTM0o0uWr///@vW/ZftzgHAA) (and [worse verbose version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw8hMU6GaSwEIcktzSjILijLzShSKUssUcvNzUhQSFbS1MyGy@WWpClalRVy1////1y37r1ucAwA))

Comment: `move :ur` Move my what? :P The increment thing is much cleaner though.

Comment: @ASCII-only you didn't forget it :p

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ??? I didn't forget what

Comment: @ASCII-only `CycleChop`...but you forgot `Increment` (or whatever it's called)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 43 <s>46</s> bytes

```
$/\;u:\s/':(!$u;:'@^!@Wu;oSU;o+<u(;;oN;(!|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/19FP8a61CqmWF9dykpDUaXU2krdIU7RIbzUOj841Dpf26ZUw9o6389aQ7Hm/38A)

Cubified

```
      $ / \
      ; u :
      \ s /
'  : ( ! $ u ; : ' @ ^
! @ W u ; o S U ; o + <
u ( ; ; o N ; ( ! | . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgJCAvIFwKICAgICAgOyB1IDoKICAgICAgXCBzIC8KJyAaIDogKCAhICQgdSA7IDogJyBAIF4KISBAIFcgdSA7IG8gUyBVIDsgbyArIDwKdSAoIDsgOyBvIE4gOyAoICEgfCAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=Cg==&speed=20)

Have managed to shave a few more of this, but it was a bit more difficult than I thought.  There is a substitute character after the first quote to give me 26.

- `'<sub>` push 26 onto the stack as the base number
- `:(!` duplicate base as a counter, decrement, test for truthy
- `u` on true skip the `$` command and u-turn to the right

  - `So;u` push 32, output as character, pop 32 and u-turn right onto the decrement
- `$` on false jump the next `u` command
- `;:'@^` pop, duplicate the base number, push 64 onto stack and redirect into a torturous route
- `$\s/:\/u;$` this is the order of the steps on the top face.  It boils down to swap the counter with the 64. Ends with a skip over the redirect that put it here.
- `<+o;U` redirect to add, output character, pop, u-turn left
- `(!` decrement, test for truthy. If true starts on a path which hits the u-turn and goes back to the redirect.
- `|(;No` on false, reflect, redundant test, redundant decrement, pop, push 10 and output character
- `;;(u!@W` pop down to the base number, decrement, u-turn right onto truthy test, halt if false otherwise change lane onto the duplicate at the beginning.  Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 37 bytes

```perl
}{$\=$"x$-++.($a=$_.$a).$/.$\for A..Z
```

### Explanation

Since `-p` is being used with no input, the leading `}{` is to break out of the implicit `while(<STDIN>){` that's added. This builds the string, in reverse, into `$\` which is implicitly output after any content that is `print`ed. `for` each char in `A..Z`, `$\` is set to `$-` (which starts as `0` and is post-incremented for the next loop) `$"`s (which is the record separator and is initialised to space) to indent the string, concatenated with `$a` (which is prepended with `$_`, the current letter from the `for` loop), followed by `$/` (the line terminator, defaults to `"\n"`) and the existing contents of `$\`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@2WiXGVkWpQkVXW1tPQyXRViVeTyVRU09FX08lJi2/SMFRTy/q//9/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 37 bytes

```perl
$#@-=say$"x$#@,reverse@@for\(@@=A..Z)
```

### Explanation

This approach outputs the string in order directly. `for` each char in the reference (`\(...)`) to `@@` (which is set to `A..Z`), this runs the loop once for each letter, `@@`'s final index is decremented by the result of outputting (`say`, includes a final newline) `$"` (space) 'the final index of `@@` times', followed by the `reverse` of `@@`. Using the return from `say` as the decrement means that the output happens before the final index is removed avoiding the need to add another entry to the list. So in the first iteration this outputs 25 spaces and `Z` to `A`, then 24 spaces and `Y` to `A` ... then 1 space and `BA` and 0 spaces and `A`.

I feel like it should be possible to remove some syntax here. I played around with a way to define a list that shrinks but doesn't stop the loop halfway through and the `\(...)` seems to do just that, whereas `[...]` is seen as one list entry instead. Also trying to find a non-word character that works with the `$#_` notation was trickier than I'd hoped, `@;` - my usual go-to results in evaluation of `$#` (which is removed).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19F2UHXtjixUkWpAsjUKUotSy0qTnVwSMsvitFwcLB11NOL0vz//19@QUlmfl7xf11fUz1DAz0DAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>54</strike> 52 bytes

```ruby
25.downto 0{|n|puts' '*n+[*?A..?Z][0..n].reverse*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/38hULyW/PK8kX8GguiavpqC0pFhdQV0rTztay95RT88@KjbaQE8vL1avKLUstag4VUtdvfb/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 83 bytes

```
[print(' '*i+''.join([chr(64+i)for i in range(i+1,0,-1)]))for i in range(25,-1,-1)]
```

My first answer on codegolf :)

Comment: A belated welcome to PPCG! nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) + [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 50 bytes

```
s/^/printf %25s;printf %s {Z..A}/e
:
p
s/ \S//
t
d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD9Ov6AoM68kTUHVyLTYGsYuVqiO0tNzrNVP5bLiKuAq1leICdbX5yrhAuoBAA)

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 51 bytes

```
printf %s {Z..A}|sed 'h
s/./ /g
G
:
s/ [^ ]//p
t
d'
```

Building on [@DigitalTrauma's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141748/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvgf4BjiYaukn19Qol@cmqKflJlnpQISU/pfUJSZV5KmoFqsUB2lp@dYWwOUV1DP4CrW19NX0E/ncueyArIVouMUYvX1C7hKuFLU//8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Z±{Xf}⁰¼
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=WiVCMSU3QlhmJTdEJXUyMDcwJUJD,v=0.12)

Comment: Just curious, how long is the compressed version?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing TL;DR way too long. SOGLs compression sucks at (and is _specifically_ made not for) repetitive stuff. It'd be very hard to tell as the compression isn't automated (automation would make it take `701 choose x` attempts for any integer x) but a rough attempt was 450 bytes :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 bytes

```perl
$_=$"x26 .join'',reverse A..Z,Z;say while s/ \S//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZFqcLITEEvKz8zT11dpyi1LLWoOFXBUU8vSifKujixUqE8IzMnVaFYXyEmWF////9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Comment: Looks like you're missing the first `A`, but seems that can be fixed by changing `$"x25` to `$"x26`!

Comment: When I added the extra `Z`, I forgot to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>75</s> 74 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [Rick Hitchcock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42260/rick-hitchcock)*

```
f=(a=65,b='',c)=>a>90?'':f(a+1,b+' ',c=String.fromCharCode(a)+[c])+`
`+b+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYj0dbMVCfJVl1dJ1nT1i7RztLAXl3dKk0jUdtQJ0lbXQEobhtcUpSZl66XVpSf65yRWOQM1KuRqKkdnRyrqZ3AlaCdpJ38Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI01DU/M/AA)

Comment: Save a byte by initializing `b` (`b=''`), then taking `b` out of the square brackets.

Comment: @RickHitchcock. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```
(dotimes(i 26)(format t"~v@{ ~}~a
"(- 25 i)(subseq"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"i)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJb8kMze1WCNTwchMUyMtvyg3sUShRKmuzKFaoa62LpFLSUNXwchUIVNTo7g0qTi1UCkqMiI8LDQkOCgwwN/P18fby9PD3c3VxdnJUSlTU1Pz/38A)

Two bytes less thanks to @Ascii-only!

Comment: [82](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJb8kMze1WCNTwchMUyMtvyg3sUShRKmuzKFaoa62LpFLSUNXwchUIVNTo7g0qTi1UCkqMiI8LDQkOCgwwN/P18fby9PD3c3VxdnJUSlTU1Pz/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP (<strike>63</strike> <strike>58</strike> 55 bytes)

This is possibly my favorite strange corner of PHP, a corner which it inherits from Perl:

```
for($c=A;$c!=AA;$q="$s$z 
$q",$s.=" ")$z=$c++.$z;echo$q;
```

This outputs the trailing newline, as explicitly permitted. This can be run in `php -r` to save the opening `<?php` needed to put this in a file.

Explanation: when a variable containing the string `'A'` is incremented in PHP, it becomes `'B'` and then `'C'` and so on up until `'Z'` becomes `'AA'`. There is no digit before `'A'` to start with in this madcap algebra, and the decrement operator does not undo it, so we save the incrementally reversed alphabet to `$z` (which defaults to `NULL` which when it gets concatenated with a string behaves like the empty string -- the same happens with `$s` and `$q`). Whitespace is accumulated in `$s` and the whole string is accumulated backwards in variable `$q` which means we have to echo it at the end.

Thanks to [Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus) for golfing off my curly braces and telling me that I don't need to take a penalty for inline-evaluation flags like `-r`.

Comment: That´s 57 bytes, if you use a linux linebreak. `-r` is free. Two bytes shorter: `for($c=A;$c!=AA;$q="$s$z\n$q",$s.=" ")$z=$c++.$z;echo$q;`

Comment: @Titus thanks, gave you a kudos in the answer.

Comment: nm. Just note that `-R` and `-F` are _not_ free. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags/2428#2428

Comment: I believe you can save a byte if you use `$c<AA`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Maybe you can; I can't. equality/comparison is going to be by strings, which is a lexical equality/comparison. The first invalid string is AA which is lexically between the valid strings A and B, making any comparator not work nicely.

Comment: @CRDrost Just saying "It doesn't seem like it will work because [...]" is enough... No need for your "Maybe you can; I can't." . . .

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sorry, I was too terse. I was thinking when I wrote that, "maybe there is a way to shuffle things around without gaining bytes so that the A case happens first and then we can detect AA vs. B but I do not think that I am smart enough to see it." I didn't mean to be flippant and I will try to watch out for that in the future.

Comment: `B` is greater than `AA`. `!$c[1]` would work, but it doesn´t save anything.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 8 bytes

```
G_.<XFo}h-
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=47+5F+BC+B0+6F+7D+68+2D&input=&warnings=1&hex=1)

```
           -  o = 0
G_         -    reversed(alphabet)
  .<       -   suffixes(^)
    XF     -  for i in ^:
      o    -      o++
       }   -     ^ * 2
        h  -    ^ + 1
         - -   i.lpad(" ", ^)
           - for i in reversed(^):
           -  print i
```

I can see the right language doing this in 6 bytes if they had a builtin for `prepend n spaces to string` as well as what Pyke does

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <strike>71</strike> 69 bytes

```
for i in range(26):print(' '*(25-i)+'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'[i:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hM06qgKDOvRENdQV1Lw8hUN1NTWz0qMiI8LDQkOCgwwN/P18fby9PD3c3VxdnJUT060ypW8////wA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question does already have multiple Python answers (don't worry, we don't discourage duplicate answers), but still, be sure to check out our [tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page, to see if you can shave anymore bytes off. Also, feel free to browse our [active challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active) to see if anything catches your eye. Hope you enjoy it here!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for the warm welcome! Thanks to you I decided to take the time to try and golf my code a bit more. Although it took me almost 2 hours to find the obvious save, I had a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> 67 bytes

```python
i=26
while-~i:print' '*i+''.join(map(chr,range(65,91)))[i::-1];i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWyIyrPCMzJ1W3LtOqoCgzr0RdQV0rU1tdXS8rPzNPIzexQCM5o0inKDEvPVXDzFTH0lBTUzM608pK1zDWOlPX1vD/fwA)

Comment: [This is why I love string literals - 65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWyIyrPCMzJ1W3LtOqoCgzr0RdQV0rU1vJ0cnZxdXN3cPTy9vH188/IDAoOCQ0LDwiMkopOtPKStcw1jpT19bw/38A) :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 85 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 53c0 05a2 2223 c2c3 4243 8283 0203 fcfd  S..."#..BC......
0000010: 7c7d bcbd 3c3d dcdd 5c5d 9c9d 1cb9 7069  |}..<=..\]....pi
0000020: 2159 0789 ea49 524d 825a a255 12a9 8e28  !Y...IRM.Z.U...(
0000030: 5544 a821 a882 803c 5e59 3c72 3865 7088  UD.!...<^Y<r8ep.
0000040: 6315 c522 8621 82c6 47e1 21b1 e12c 280d  c..".!..G.!..,(.
0000050: 2681 d811 00                             &....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZAxSwNBEIV7f8WLgqSQZXd2525WzkYFsbBRUkRUuJ3diKAQhHT628@5JLWvGKZ5H@@9sivls73vvqbJH3QJjurheSQQUYSSRiRKEUIS4clHbHRTgSfn3OmZc9c3bq@TPSAYote@omipiBorqtYKVq7ImiuClozedxn4@XVuuHLu5XUGbD8OCDIEBc7wvWS0MWUwpWoBeMRIzAg0ZkgjARZrc94/Prhnt7JveUDEuQinhFEo2BGC@KjgZtioPSFKx5ZCDLG6dQuzDm/r4Vva9lgkGaKLgaFM5u6MI6QdUt@CxSsBLZCCxNsWalPMkLv5XCyPCJ6LdBJQJQR4j/90Pk8wTX8)

Comment: A reason behind the downvote, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe because the language is really a glorified text compressor? I haven't downvoted fwiw

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>79</s> 73 bytes

```
Column@(T=Table)[T[" ",26-i]<>ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[-i;;1;;-1]],{i,26}]
```

or without `Alphabet`

## Mathematica, <s>75</s> 66 bytes

```
Column@Array[Table[" ",26-#]<>Reverse@CharacterRange[65,91-#]&,26]
```

*thanks @JungHwanMin for golfing more both of my answers*

Comment: `CharacterRange` should be shorter than `FromCharacterCode`.

Comment: it doesn't have "reverse" in it. If you can make it work without reverse please let me know

Comment: `Reverse[CharacterRange[65,90]][[#-27;;]]` is the same as `Reverse@CharacterRange[65,91-#]`

Comment: Also `Reverse[ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[;;27-i]]]` can be reduced to `ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[-i;;1;;-1]]` (got rid of `Reverse`!)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>31</s> 27 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{`c$(x#32),65+|!x+1}@/:|!26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/vzohWUWjQtnYSFPHzFS7RrFC27DWQd@qRtHI7P9/AA)

**Explanation:**

Iterate over the list of `25..0`, each iteration create the reverse alphabet joined with x many spaces:

```
{`c$(x#32),65+|!x+1}@/:|!26 / solution
                        !26 / til 26 (0..25)
                       |    / reverse (25..0)
                    @/:     / each (25, 24, 23...)
{                  }        / lambda function
                x+1         / increment x (25->26)
               !            / til x (0..26)
              |             / reverse
           65+              / add 65, 0+65 = ASCII "A"
          ,                 / join
    (x#32)                  / x take 32 (e.g 32, x many times)
 `c$                        / cast everything to characters
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>146</s> <s>142</s> <s>141</s> <s>140</s> <s>137</s> 133 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to MD XF

-4 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#define F for(i=26-g;i;--i)std::cout<<
void f(){for(int g=1,i;g<27;g+=2){F ' ';--g;F char(64+i);std::cout<<'\n';}}
```

Comment: Why would you `int g=26` immediately before `g=0`?

Comment: @MDXF For reasons that went out through the window when golfing, i guess :)

Comment: Changing the last two lines to `#define F for(i=26-g;i;--i)std::cout<<` and `void f(){for(int g=1,i;g<27;g+=2){F ' ';--g;F char(64+i);std::cout<<'\n';}}` should save you a few bytes.

Comment: You don't need a space between `F` and `' '` (but do need ASCII or compatible encoding).

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 140 bytes

Still very ungolfed, will do it later!

```
set n 26;time {set c $n;append s [string repe \  $n];incr n -1;time {append s [format %c [expr 65+[incr c -1]]]} $c; append s \n} 26;puts $s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc3BCsIwEATQX5lDPIkHBXvJp6Q5lO0qAbsumxUE6bfHVESPw7xhnG6tVXYITkP0sjBeWyQEiZMqy4yKVN2KXGGsjBG9y7EIWV8djt/VH1/utkyOHSHxUw3DeZ8@mrrOOa8IFPHzo6zbtz68ItTW3g)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 142 bytes

```
set n 26;while \$n {set c $n;append s [string repe \  $n];incr n -1;time {append s [format %c [expr 65+[incr c -1]]]} $c; append s \n};puts $s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxDsIwEETRq0xhqogCJNLsURwX0bIES8li2YuIFOXsxlBAO/@N8VxrEYPi3NPrHmfB4BTbZ2M4pTEl0SsKfLEcdUKW1AxaCxSVc7seT2RxEWx/fHvkZTQcGF7WlNFfOv/V3HQIYYdjws8PulN6WoErtb4B)

Comment: Hmmm, I already golfed something similar on the "my italic" version of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110360/29325

Comment: The latest one appears to be wrong

Comment: [100?](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVPBgKskMzdVobqgtKRYITotvyg3sURBNTq1oqBIwdRQ10hLJTMWKFFcUpSZl65QlKgQFRkRHhYaEhwUGODv5@vj7eXp4e7m6uLs5KigkqlgZBYba52Zl1ykkFkL5Pz/DwA)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVGhupYLxMhUsDTkKsnMTVWoLigtKVaITssvyk0sUVCNTq0oKFKIzsxLLgIq0jWM1TW2jAXKQ3TDlSUrqGTGqiTGxtYqGJn9/w8A) including `set` in the `format`. But I think your code doesn't answer the exact challenge.

Comment: [a proposition in 92 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWCE6Lb8oN7FEQTU6taKgSMHITDc6My@5SCEzNrZYobo2Nrq4pCgzL12hKFFBPSoyIjwsNCQ4KDDA38/Xx9vL08PdzdXF2clRQSUTqDW2Fkj8/w8A) though I think this possibly could be shortened with a unique string.

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWCE6Lb8oN7FEQTU6taKgSMHUWNdIKzozL7lIITM2FihdXFKUmZeuUJSooB4VGREeFhoSHBQY4O/n6@Pt5enh7ubq4uzkqKCSqWBkFhtbCyT//wcA) with a single string per iteration

Comment: @ASCII-only: thanks for pointing my error

Comment: @david: thanks for pointing my error

Answer (score 2):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 102 bytes

This is just a very straight-forward implementation, nothing fancy.

```
{@setV 25}{@forfrom"Z"to"A"}{@callstr_repeat intoX" ",V}{@callrange intoZ _,"A"}{@echolX,Z}{@incby-1V}
```

Try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a31f7d1b8532385cc135cc1bf64e05d702ebcce4

---

**Ungolded:**

```
{@set spaces 25}
{@for i from "Z" to "A"}
    {@call str_repeat into padding " ", spaces}
    {@call range into letters i, "A"}
    {@echo EOL, padding, letters}
    {@inc by -1 spaces}
{@/}
```

Should be almost self-explainatory

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 25 bytes

Fixed. Thanks to Martin Ender for the help fixing it!

```
'[,65>W%_,,_Sf*W%\@f>.+N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xz1ax8zULlzVyl1HJz44TStcNcY9zU5P20/r/38A)

Explanation:

```
'[,65>W%_,,_Sf*W%\@f>.+N*
'[,65>                     e# From the cjam golfing tips, generate A-Z
      W%                   e# Reverse the array: Z-A
        _,                 e# Take the size of that range (so, 26)
          ,                e# Make a range 0..25
           _               e# Dupe that range
              f*           e# For each value of that range
             S             e# Repeat a space that amount of times
                W%         e# Reverse this list of strings
                  \        e# Swap the top and the second elements of the stack
                   @       e# Brings the first stack el. to the top
                    f>     e# For each value in that range, remove N elements from the alphabet (generate ZYX..., until, CBA, BA, A).
                      .+   e# Vectorized append (appends space with the alphabet chunks)
                        N* e# Join with newline
```

Comment: You can reverse an array with `W%` (i.e. take every element starting from the end).

Comment: Or `-1%` if `W` isn't sure to be `-1`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks! Fixed it that way (Now I wish I had a "reverse rang", hehe).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer shouldn't be an issue here (I also went the "functional" route), but thanks for the precision

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 76 bytes

```
{for(;++j<27;)printf"%"53-2*j"s\n",substr("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA",++z)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaWzvLxsjcWrOgKDOvJE1JVcnUWNdIK0upOCZPSae4NKm4pEhDKSoyIjwsNCQ4KDDA38/Xx9vL08PdzdXF2clRSUdbu0qz9v9/QwA)

Tried 3-4 different versions, including double `for` loop, this is the fewest bytes I could come up with.

Not sure if I should add 1 byte since it does require some input to produce output.

Answer (score 2):

## vim, 46 bytes

```
:set nf=alpha
25a <ESC>aZ<ESC>qaylp<CTRL+X>q24@aqayyphxxq24@a
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
:set nf=alpha    " add letters to the set of number formats used by CTRL+A, CTRL+X
25a <ESC>aZ<ESC> " add the leading spaces and the Z
qaylp<CTRL+X>q   " record macro to copy and decrement the last letter, and
24@a             " run 24 times
qayyphxxq        " record macro to copy/paste the last line, and delete the last space and first letter. 
24@a             " run 24 times.
```

`<ESC>` and `<CTRL+X>` are 0x1B and 0x18 respectively.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36o4tUQhL802MacgI5HLyDRRQToxSrowsTKnQKLQyMQhEcisLMioqABz/v8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 60 bytes

I couldn't beat @Snack's answer, but here are some solutions that I found interesting:

```
25.downto 0{|i|$><<" "*i;i.downto 0{|e|$><<(65+e).chr};puts}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/38hULyW/PK8kX8GguiazRsXOxkZJQUkr0zoTSTwVLK5hZqqdqqmXnFFUa11QWlJc@/8/AA)

I'm also particularly entertained by calculating the spaces this way and was saddened that it wasn't shorter:

```
z="";(?A..?Z).each{|e| (?A..e).each{|k| z+=k}; z+=" "*(z.size**0.5-1)+?\n};puts z.reverse
```

At least it's the only answer that uses a square root!

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 105 bytes

```java
z->{for(int i=0;i<26;)System.out.printf("%"+(51-i*2)+"s%n","ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA".substring(i++));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5dS8MwGIXv9yteAoPE2qADvek20Pmtc2r9Fi/SrB1vbZOSvBno2G@vtXh14DmHh1OqtYptk5ty@dU2IatQg66U9zBXaGAzAPinnhR1sba4hLrreEoOzerjE5RbedFPAcrOJwNhJYtgNKE1cmaND3XuxouszDVNwcEE2p94uims42gIcLKX4Hh0mIj021NeSxtINp2dCs6GLOIH@zHujETE/NCwXfb@9vry/PSYPtzfLW7nN9dXlxfnZ6cns@MjJn3IfH@MYxQJkWzbpD/mpNI6b4ibUFXij20H2/YX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
for i in range(26):print(" "*(25-i)+"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"[i:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hM06qgKDOvRENJQUlLw8hUN1NTWykqMiI8LDQkOCgwwN/P18fby9PD3c3VxdnJUSk60ypW8/9/AA)

This is my first challenge. I hope i've done this right.

Edit: Had a 26 where a 25 should have been.

Comment: Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 21 bytes

```
({.~1-2*#)\.u:90-i.26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/zWq9eoMdY20lDVj9EqtLA10M/WMzP5rcinpKain2VqpK@go1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrpP0HAA)

### original version

```
(,~' '#~<:@#)\.|.26$65|.a.
```

- `26$65|.a.` get A - Z
- `|.` reverse them
- `\.` take successive prefixes from the right side
- `(,~' '#~<:@#)` append to each one (`,~`) a number of spaces equal to the length of the prefix minus 1 (`<:@#`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/zV06tQV1JXrbKwclDVj9Gr0jMxUzExr9BL1/mtyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5Cuk/QcA)

Comment: @FrownyFrog thanks!  I was not aware of the negative trick with `{.`

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>52</s> <s>48</s> 53 bytes

```
do x<-scanr(:)[]['Z','Y'..'A'];tail$(' '<$x)++x++"\n"
```

Comment: `tails` requires an import, though you can use `scanr(:)[]` instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHJCYAwEADAVoIIq0QtwONhDb68Hks8McaQjZDqXWcOpGvVmqmZeHlEqHNSaFxSpuM8wgAZ9FAU0MJceTx1nICAOg6plEHKaDIR33iaxr6@804Qf2rTuBPnytof "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Visual Basic .NET (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/), 134 bytes

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Dim S,I,J
For I=0To 25
S=Space(25-I)
For J=0To 25-I
S+=Chr(90-I-J)
Next
Console.WriteLine(S)
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc29CsIwFEDh/T5FxhR7pRQ6OGSqFVKMSwTntL1gIM2V/ohvH6V2OsM3nLefVxewc7PvMdKCI0dOyfCwBhIG7NoJ43yEsx@FzXXewoUnoVVxZ1FWYJV9uZ5kWaHONmp3Qg32oOrnJE8FamwzuNFngZrjzIGOj8kvdPWRpN2liYP47bb@/yl9AQ)

Comment: So much BASIC!!

Comment: @MDXF BASIC is Life!!!!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
for x in range(26):print(' '*(25-x),*map(chr,range(90-x,64,-1)),sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hM06qgKDOvRENdQV1Lw8hUt0JTRys3sUAjOaNIB6LG0kC3QsfMREfXUFNTpzi1wFZdXfP/fwA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
∧Ẓa₁ụ?b{~wṢ}ᵐ&ẉ⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9icmFjaHlsb2cy///iiKfhupJh4oKB4bulP2J7fnfhuaJ94bWQJuG6ieKKpf//)

Prints with a single trailing newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 163 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1RCsAwCEO/k1PkamUU1r9BBzu@qzrHpkhQXsy1j7PPo23dTBIgiJQYrRgQ8rOWIg7yIoqjMy7pKUnMXUrf/9VaAmRmlH6ynjC8UTS7AQ)

```
                                    (s = space, t = tab, l = linefeed)
sssttstsl   push 26                 For x = 26 times

lssl        start: ""
sls         dup (Stack: [26, 26])       For y = x times

lsssl       spaces:
ssstl       push 1
tsst        sub                             decrement space counter
sls         dup
ltstl       jz end_spaces                   if space counter > 0
ssstsssssl  push 32
tlss        outchar                             print space
lslsl       jmp spaces
lsstl       end_spaces:                 next y

sll         drop                        drop y
sls         dup (Stack: [26, 26])

lssssl      letters:
sls         dup                         for y = x to 0
ssstssssssl push "@"
tsss        add (Stack: [26, 26, "Z"])      add y to "@" to get start letter
tlss        outchar                         print that letter
ssstl       push 1
tsst        sub                             decrement y
sls         dup
ltsstl      jz end_letters
lslssl      jmp letters                 next y
lssstl      end_letters:

sll         drop                        drop y
ssstl       push 1
tsst        sub                         decrement x
sls         dup
ltsttl      jz end
ssststsl    push 10
tlss        outchar                     print newline
lsll        jmp start               next x
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
kA¦₄ʁ꘍RṘ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kA%C2%A6%E2%82%84%CA%81%EA%98%8DR%E1%B9%98%E2%81%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

could be -1 byte by replacing the `⁋` at the end with the `j` flag

-4 bytes from the initial working version thanks to ovs
some golfs were proposed by other people but they broke the answer
-2 bytes thanks to Aaron Miller

```
kA¦₄ʁ꘍RṘ    Full Program
kA          "ABC...XYZ"
  ¦         "A", "AB", "ABC", ..., "ABC...XYZ"
   ₄        26
    ʁ       0..25
     ꘍      a + " " * b (returns "A", "AB ", "ABC  ", ...)
      R     Reverse each ("A", " BA", "  CBA", ...)
       Ṙ    Reverse the entire list
        ⁋   Join on newlines
```

Comment: [9 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=kA%C2%A6%E1%B9%98%C6%9BL%E2%80%B9%24%EA%98%8D&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Lyxal i refuse to turn to the dark side of (ab)using flags :P

Comment: [fine then. 10 bytes flagless](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kA%C2%A6%E1%B9%98%C6%9BL%E2%80%B9%24%EA%98%8D%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: `kA` should be `kZ` since the alphabet is supposed to be backwards.

Comment: @AaronMiller Oh, I didn't notice Lyxal's golf broke that lol. Also, I didn't realize that was a built-in either. Thanks!

Comment: [8 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jr&code=kZ%C2%A6%E1%B9%98%C6%9BL%E2%80%B9%EA%98%8D&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: The output is currently different from the one in the challenge. `kA¦ṘvṘƛL‹꘍` works for 10, but there might be something shorter

Comment: @ovs ah, can't believe I missed that, it's been broken for a long time now. thanks

Comment: [8 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=kA%C2%A6%E2%82%84%CA%81%EA%98%8DR%E1%B9%98&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>84</s> <s>80</s> 73 bytes

```python
for i in range(25,-1,-1):print(' '*i+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[i::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hUR9cQiDStCooy80o01BXUtTK1lRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz9/AMCg4JDQsPCIyKjlKIzrax0DWM1//8HAA)

Saved 7 bytes thanks to `@Mr. Xcoder`

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw8hMR9cQiDStCooy80o01BXUtTK1lRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz9/AMCg4JDQsPCIyKjlKIzrax0DWM1//8HAA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I forgot that the literal alphabet was shorter than `import string`

Comment: This prints the top line twice with an extra space. Change 26 to 25 to fix it

Comment: @Cowabunghole you saw nothing ;)

Comment: I know porting Lynns would be shorter but `for i in range(26):print(' '*(25-i)+"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"[i:])` saves another four bytes.

Comment: This approach gets down to 66 bytes:

`i=26`
`while i:i-=1;print(' '*i+"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"[-i-1:])`

Comment: @awatts You can replace the `[-i-1:]` with `[~i:]` to get it down to 64.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
;26Çn26 î +Bw tZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39rI7HB7npGZwuF1CtpO5QolUf//6wYBAA)

Comment: Think you can save a byte with the equivalent of `;Bm_YnZl ...`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
V_UG+*dN_<rG1hN
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V_U26%2B%2adN_%3CrG1hN&debug=0).

Comment: @Dave No, that is lowercase. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
j_.e+*kd_rb1._G
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_.e%2B%2akd_rb1._G&debug=0)**

---

## Explanation

- `j_.e+*kd_rb1._G` - Full program.
- `._G` - Prefixes of the lowercase alphabet.
- `.e` - Enumerated map, with `k` as the indexes and `b` as the values.
- `*kd` - A space repeated a number of times equal to the current index.
- `_rb1` - And the current element converted to uppercase.
- `+` - String concatenation.
- `_` - Reverse.
- `j` - Join by newlines.

Comment: similar idea, but `V_._Gs+m\ NrN1` is 14 btyes

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;Båi ËiEçÃÔ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O0LlaSDLaUXnw9Q)

```
;Båi ËiEçÃÔ
;B              :Uppercase alphabet
  å             :Cumulatively reduce by
   i            :  Prepending
     Ë          :Map each element a 0-based index E
      i         :  Prepend
       Eç       :  Space repeated E times
         Ã      :End map
          Ô     :Reverse
                :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>75</s> 72 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox)*

```c
i=27;main(j){for(;--i;)for(printf("\n%*c",j=i,64+i);--j;putchar(64+j));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/T1sjcOjcxM08jS7M6Lb9Iw1pXN9NaE8QqKMrMK0nTUIrJU9VKVtLJss3UMTPRztQEqsiyLigtSc5ILNIAimRpalrX/v8PAA)

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/T1sjcOjcxM08jS7M6Lb9Iw1pXN9NaE8QqKMrMK0nTUIrJU9VKVtLJss3UMTPRztQEqsiyLigtSc5ILNIAimRpalrX/v8PAA)

Comment: You probably ought to mention that this is for ASCII or compatible environments.

Comment: 67 bytes: `i=27;main(j){for(;j=--i*2;)for(puts("");--j;putchar(j>i?32:64+j));}`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 82 bytes

```
$l=strlen($s=$argv[1]);while($l)echo strrev(str_pad(substr($s,0,$l),$l+$l--))."
";
```

Called with `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` as an argument.

Do I get bonus points because it produces the desired effect with any string? :P

Comment: I'm not sure a solution requiring specific user input is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//github.com/aaronryank/simplestack), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
À¦\^(-(1ß-);%\1^ß1ö
À                    « push alphabet                       »;
 ¦                   « swap case                           »;
  \                  « reverse                             »;
   ^                 « push length                         »;
    (                « do                                  »;
     -               «  decrement string length            »;
      (1..)          «  while top of stack truthy          »;
        ß            «   print space                       »;
         -           «   decrement string length           »;
           ;         «  pop string length                  »;
            %        «  print string                       »;
             \1      «  knock first character off string   »;
               ^     «  push length                        »;
                ß1   «  print newline                      »;
                  ö  «  exit without implicit output if top of stack falsy  »;
                     « implicit infinite loop              »;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@//9ww6FlMXEauhqGh@frGmpaq8boxsQdnm@oqfb/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 17 bytes

```
AL«]' '*\A\ùi.‹»;
```

### Explained

```
AL«]' '*\A\ùi.‹»;
AL                  # Length of the Alphabet, 26.
  «            »;   # For each, numbers 1 through 26 inclusive.
   ]                # Duplicate the index eg.                   (5, 5)
    ' '*            # Repeat ' ' by the index.                  (5, '     ')
        \           # Flip the top of the stack,                ('     ', 5)
         A\         # Push the alphabet under the top.          ('     ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 5)
           ù        # Get the first n characters.               ('     ', 'ABCDE')
            i       # Reverse the top of the stack.             ('     ', 'EDCBA')
             .      # Concatenate.                              ('     EDCBA')
              ‹     # Rotate left, to remove the extra space.   ('    EDCBA ')
```

This leaves each result on the stack, and RProgN2 implicitely prints the stack upside down, which conveniently gives us our result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9/R59DqWHUFda0Yx5jDOzP1HjXsPLTb@v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 89 bytes

```
1 s=25,a$="ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
2  ?" "*s;a$
3 a$=a$(2 TO),s-=1
4 IF s>0 THEN 2
5  ?a$
```

Bit of string splicing, rinse and repeat

Answer (score 1):

## VB, 167 bytes

```
i = 26

For a = i To 1 Step -1
    For j = a To 1 Step -1
        c = c + "  "
        b = b + Chr(64 + j)
    Next
    
    d = d & c & b & vbNewLine
    c = ""
    b = ""
Next
msgbox d
```

first time to participate but i'm not competing to everyone, just myself. lol

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I am not sure about VB, but can you remove the whitespace, like `b=b+Chr(64+j)`? That would save quite a bit here.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam VB automatically adds spaces when programming in an IDE. I don't think they're required, though. I've seen confusion before about whether to remove them or ignore them.

Comment: @mbomb007 hmm, can you run VB from a file without opening it in an IDE?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam When I deal with Basic's auto-indentation, I usually open a separate text editor, remove as much whitespace as possible, then paste that into the IDE. If auto-format still works and the code runs as expected, I post the code from the text editor.

Comment: This code can be consensed to something like: `i=26┘
For a=iTo 1Step -1┘
For j=aTo 1Step -1┘
c=c+"  "┘
b=b+Chr(64+j)┘
Next┘
d=d&c&b&Chr(13)┘
c=""┘
b=c┘
Next┘
msgbox d` (used `┘` as line-breaks...) Note the `FOR`-instructions, Basic usually doesn't need a space beteen a number literal and the following instruction.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) Following on from the other suggestions, there's plenty that can be golfed out of this. Here's a quick pass I took over it for 103 bytes: `for a=26to 1step-1:c="":b="":for j=a to 1step-1:c=c+" ":b=b+chr(64+j):next:d=d&c&b&vbcrlf:next:msgbox d`

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 87 + 18 bytes

```cs
_=>new int[26].Select((x,i)=>"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA".Substring(i).PadLeft(51-2*i))
```

Also included in byte count:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBdT8MwDHzvr4j2lKAtgknwsrXSKO0YdGPQwfgQQlnmgqUugSSFIrTfXloqmLgHyzqfT2dL25PaQFVYVM8k/bQONjxB9TbwlNiAfRUSfulQ5zlIh1pZPgYFBqX35ZEaMhfWktFP3zINrBMOJXnXuCZTgYqyv9FO1CAulByicl0yiVSxASNWOQytM3WmICAZ8asnP1DwQWrRQ//okafQJKG07CLzg8793e3y5nqRXl3OL2bT5PxscjqOo5PweNThabFqnSgyPhfrBDJHDw96/T1krBr8C5LRfcYXOkHrKOOxNpGQL7QkfkDC@mqdA18adFA/CGjJ2G5767V1W30D)

This outputs a collection of strings (for each line).

Explanation:

```cs
_ =>                                   // A function that takes one argument (unused)
    new int[26].                       // Create new collection size 26
    Select((x, i) =>                   // Replace every member with
        "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"   //    Our alphabet
        .Substring(i)                  //    Take it's part based on line number
        .PadLeft(51 - 2 * i)           //    Add spaces to the left
    )
```

Here's non-kolmogorov version (for any string) - 76 + 18 bytes:

```cs
a=>new int[a.Length].Select((x,i)=>a.Substring(i).PadLeft(a.Length*2-1-2*i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LbsIwEDyTr3A5IBuBpXKliRRCQmnDo4SWPg/GLGDJODR2ClXFt9OEABXq7GU1uzszy3WdxwnsUy3UAkXf2sCKhkJ9Ni3FVqDXjMOJ9mIpgRsRK007oCAR3PqxUAYumdbIPfQFk0MbZgRHX7GYoR4TCpPz6G8pR5AqfqNNkkWooa6v0hUkbCrhyDkOmiN7z2xHwQYJZd4YDUEtzPKDRpBHwnhbE8R2GI3SaXGEBaFDNgthbvBpvdqoX9cbVUHIvmmVioj5bqa5Ts2R2iyFBITxgUM28rJ3Ywl0BJmaUIAJQVc2UqmUqFIpTnOi/K7KpJC4/C7HvJAjdByHQhtMaBAnPuNLvEW2c/aYJMLAwWRLSJan9H9AjjF3Z4@i21m7/evL8@TpcRyNHoaDfi@8v@vedgK/7bVcyxu0/c4gDKy@e1ktd9xz@78)

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
raze@/:(1_')\[(25#" ";(|).Q.A)]
```

**Example:**

```
q)raze@/:(1_')\[(25#" ";(|).Q.A)]
"                         ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                        YXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                       XWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                      WVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                     VUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                    UTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                   TSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                  SRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                 RQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"                QPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"               PONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"              ONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"             NMLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"            MLKJIHGFEDCBA"
"           LKJIHGFEDCBA"
"          KJIHGFEDCBA"
"         JIHGFEDCBA"
"        IHGFEDCBA"
"       HGFEDCBA"
"      GFEDCBA"
"     FEDCBA"
"    EDCBA"
"   DCBA"
"  CBA"
" BA"
,"A"
""
```

**Explanation:**

Create two lists, 1 with 25 spaces, 1 with the reversed alphabet, then drop the first item from each list and join together. Use converge `\` to terminate when the output matches previous output (hence this results in a trailing empty line):

```
raze each (1_')\[(25#" ";reverse .Q.A)] / ungolfed solution
                 (      ;            )  / two item list
                  25#" "                / 25 take " ", whitespace 25 long
                         reverse .Q.A   / .Q.A is uppercase alphabet A..Z, reverse reverses, so Z..A
          (   )\[                     ] / converge running left function with right arguments
           1_'                          / 1 drop (_) each (') removes first item from each sublist and returns result (2 lists)
raze each                               / raze reduces a list of lists, so we reduce each sublist of 2 lists to a single list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 44 bytes

```perl6
$_=chrs 32 xx 27,91...65;.say while s/\s\S//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcnBCoJAEIDh@z7FHDrGSkZGRBeFqIMI6VGIyQYcdltjdkt9@s1Lx///3iQ2i3F1P3W9eNimME2Q7teHjdY62x21xxnGni2BT1rf1kkSYz0SBagcDw6KnjtDDhoSntGwqr5L3Qb0gZ5/Vc1HDM2QCy1fXQNaRgd52SziUOUWOwPnQcgHuOBLlYThgdZCicIOBX8)

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 48 bytes

```
[26|Q=Q+chr$(a+64)][26,1,-1|?space$(b)+_s_fQ|,-b
```

### Explanation

```
[26|            FOR a = 1; a <= 26; a++
Q=Q+chr$(a+64)  Add to Q$ a chr() being a+64 (A-Z in succession)
]               NEXT (at the end of the loop, Q$ is ABC...XYZ)
[26,1,-1|       FOR b = 26; b >= 1; b--
?space$(b)      PRINT b spaces,
+_s             and a substring of
   _fQ|         Q$ reversed,
   ,-b          taking b characters from the right
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 48 bytes

```
25 65[^[$][32,1-]#%^^+[^^\-][$,1-]#,10,^][\1-\]#
```

[Online DUP interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 38 bytes (or 46 bytes in tio)

```matlab
flip([spdiags(hankel(90:-1:65)) '']')'
```

Generates the correct output at least on windows installation of Octave, but in tio to be correctly shown the character `0` should be replace by space:

```matlab
[max(32,flip(spdiags(hankel(90:-1:65))')') '']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/OjexQsPYSCctJ7NAo7ggJTMxvVgjIzEvOzVHw9LAStfQysxUU1MdCBXU1WP//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 57 bytes

```perl6
.put for (' 'Xx(25...0))Z~(('Z'...'A') »...»'A')».join
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@voLREIS2/SEFDXUE9okLDyFRPT89AUzOqTkNDPUodyFF3VNdUOLQbyDq0G8QGMrPyM/P@/wcA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
  .put              # print with trailing newline

for                 # for each of the following

  (
      ' ' 

    Xx              # cross using string repetition operator

      ( 25 ... 0 )  # from 25 down to 0
  )

  Z~                # zip using string concatenation

  (
    ( 'Z' ... 'A' ) # descending sequence of starting values
    »...»           # combine those into sequences each with an end value of 'A'
    'A'
  )».join           # combine each of the sub sequences into strings
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 119 bytes

```
>+++++[<++>>+++++<-]>+>++++[>++++++++<-]>>-[>+<---]>+++++<<<<[-[->+>.<<]>[->>>.->+<<<<]>>>.->[-<+<<<<+>>>>>]<<<<<<<.>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoVADEMPVDonCLlI6UIFQYS/@OD5a2bqW70kpft/u37nc9xVtEnAjK3wpC2NLr6Orgz3Oa9OhIfreABJGTkU55Dt4VhRv0WiGdKqFw)

Could be golfable by better initializing the tape - there is a modulo solution that would pop 90,32,26 and 10, that would also probably leave the tape a little less fragmented.

Also could combine all three loops unto one, by juggling the index as the difference from the ASCII code 'Z', or something.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/) v1.8, 93 bytes

Converted [Renzo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141766/73954) answer to Clojure.

```
(dotimes[i 26](prn(apply str(concat(repeat(- 25 i)" ")(subs"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"i)))))
```

## Explanation

```
(dotimes [i 26] ...)                 We will print 26 lines, i is between[0, 26)
(subs"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"i)  Take the string starting from position 'i'
(repeat(- 25 i)" ")                  Repeat the whitespaces, we start from 25 because the last line doesn't have whitespaces
(prn(apply str(concat(repeat(- 25 i)" ")(subs"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"i)))) Concatenate the sequence of whitespaces and the string in order to have the desired effect with 'str' next
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Kl7X/0)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <del>196</del> 134 bytes

Yes, this has no chance of winning overall, but it helps to re-familiarize myself with the language. Any improvements are welcome, but know I have not yet had time to read the [Tips or Golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java).

<del>`public class A{public static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i<26;i++){for(int j=0;j<25-i;j++)System.out.print(" ");for(char c=(char)(90-i);c>=65;c--)System.out.print(c);System.out.println();}}}`</del>

Thanks to JollyJoker for suggesting improvements. I won't get a chance to investigate lambdas for this one, but I'll remember it for the future. This is as short as I'll make this one. Eclipse kept complaining when I changed all ints to chars, so I'll look into that some more.

```java
String a(){String r="";for(int i=0;i<26;i++){for(int j=0;j<25-i;j++)r+=" ";for(char c=(char)('Z'-i);c>=65;c--)r+=c;r+="\n";}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/LasMwEEX3@YqLN5EwCiWQbCbqH3SVXR8LVXHTUR3ZjORAMf52V4nT1Qzn3oEzwV2d6fomhtPP3A@fLXv41qWEF8cR4wpI2WX28zELxzOc0uNjFVtV9NWJ4pjB9on4sN0T17Ue/2koNBy2O8MUCpfaVlhu/LcTeHufWq1f14Y1@We735E35tb0dKu/x4omafIgEULTDDwsFy1cOz7hUlzVYvX2ASfnpO/qwPE35eay6Ya86Uuc26jKB5pKOK2m@Q8)

Ungolfed:

<del>`public class A {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 25 - i; j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                for (char c = (char)(90 - i); c> = 65; c--)
                    System.out.print(c);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }`</del>

```java
String a() {
    String r = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25 - i; j++)
            r += " ";
        for (char c = (char)('Z'-i); c >= 65; c--)
            r += c; r+= "\n";
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You can give the answer as a method returning a `String` instead of a full program. Use Java 8 lambdas for the method. [Combine nested for loops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5297/58251) if you can find a way. The char 32 is space and 10 is newline; concatenate chars like `""+=c` to build a `String`.

Comment: [You can use `n->` instead of `()->`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding) even if there's no input. Using it to store a `char` inside the code _might_ be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll edit my answer in a few hours with your improvements.

Comment: You can copy / paste some [lambda boilerplate from here](https://tio.run/##vVDRasMgFH3vV1wKAyXRdWUwmDNjH7C@9LHkwaVmu1lirJqWEvLtmUv22D4NKl4uHu/xnGOljoq1Vptq/z1iY1sXoIoY7wLW/M05dfZiUdTKe3hXaPoFAJqgXakKDZvf4wTscihI7OCpiNgQK24fVMACNuBBwmhY1k8ju1wafZpoJk9RPqRWYnqIpcTpC2tNTLaifdk6omSSoMA7xlS2ElRgSdTLmvYHSWxGMDnQ@zV99TvGTC7tsxXxJTEMTofOGfBiGMVsxXYfdbTy5@jY4h6amIdsg0PzGe0rOofZnn3QDW@7wG28CrUh8zfw0M7DxPOCrCidkl4kLNm1tbxOuqTyeBOVp9tk@ZfMsBjGHw)

Comment: Avoid cast by using `'Z'` instead of `90` and changing everything from `int` to `char`

Comment: Have you tried compiling this? Because it doesn't compile... `String() a()` isn't valid in Java...

Comment: Even with copy pasta typos are possible :). Not sure why I added that, but it is fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! I allowed myself to edit your post, with a link towards an online interpreter. This is usually a good practice to show that no code issue happens! Also, your code is now 2 bytes shorter since you removed those `()`, but you hadn't updated your post with that, so I did it as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>86</s> 83 bytes

```
for x in range(25,-1,-1):print(" "*x)+"".join([chr(y+65)for y in range(x+1)][::-1])
```

Thanks to [Stephen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65836/stephen) for the 3 extra bytes.

Comment: 3? less bytes by removing extra spaces: `for x in range(25,-1,-1):print(" "*x)+"".join([chr(y+65)for y in range(x+1)][::-1])`

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 82 bytes

```
for(i=26;i;){console.log(" ".repeat(i-1)+"ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA".slice(-i--))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PWyMw601qzOjk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQ0lBSa8otSA1sUQjU9dQU1spKjIiLDQkOCgwwN/P18fby9PD3c3VxdnJUUmvOCczOVVDN1NXV1Oz9v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

-2 from dave and ven thanks guys

```
V_UG+*dNrG1=PG
```

Explanation coming when I <s>figure it out</s> wake up.

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
V26p*-25Nd>_rG1N
```

Explanation:

```
V26        26 times, could've written lG, but it's the same
   p*-25Nd Print without newline: 25-index spaces (could've used + instead of p but it's simpler to explain)
   >_rG1N  Implicit print with newline: The last index characters of the reverse uppercase alphabet
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8zIrEBL18jUL8Uuvsjd0O//fwA)

While you're here, here's [Artemis's first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141751/63757) ported into Pyth:

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>21</s> 20 bytes (non-competing)

```
J26W=tJ+*dJ>_rG1-25J
```

An explanation for Artemis's answer:

```
J26        Set J to 26
W          While...
 =tJ       Decrement J (J-=1)
 +*dJ      J spaces plus...
 >_rG1-25J The last 25-index characters of the reverse uppercase alphabet
```

I should stop writing these on my phone

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38vILNy2xEtbK8XLLr7I3VDXyNTr/38A)

Comment: Similar to this answer, but `>` doesn't seem like the way to go. How about setting G to tG, as in `V_UG+*dNrG1=tG` for 14 bytes?

Comment: @Dave similar to what answer?

Comment: Yours! This being parent lol

Comment: @Dave I knew I was doing something wrong

Comment: It's too early for this

Answer (score 1):

## Twig, 93 bytes

Twig is a template language developed to be used in PHP, which is similar to Smarty, Django or Jinja.

```
{%for a in "Z".."A"%}{{("%"~(26-loop.index)~"s%s")|format(f,range(a,"A")|join())}}
{%endfor%}
```

This code relies in the fact that the [environment option](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options) `strict_variables` defaults to `false`. Otherwise, it will break.

Try it on https://twigfiddle.com/9umogr (check the **raw** result).
If you want to copy-paste the code, make sure that you disable `strict_variables`, since the website sets that to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), <s>50 24 23</s> 22 bytes

```
{B26"P+*' '-L(}Z~}_(26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/2snITClAW0tdQV3XR6M2qq42XsPI7P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, <s>34</s> <s>23</s> 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
↑{(1-2×⍵)↑⌽⍵↑⎕A}¨⌽⍳26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HbxGoNQ12jw9Mf9W7VBPIe9ewFskCMvqmOtYdWgPmbjcz@A/mP2iY86u0DMjz9H3U1H1pvDFEWHOQMJEM8PIP/AwA)

Thanks to Adám for the help!

Explanation:

```apl
↑{(1-2×⍵)↑⌽⍵↑⎕A}¨⌽⍳26
                  ⍳26 ⍝ 1..26
                 ⌽    ⍝ Reverse, 26..1
 {             }¨     ⍝ For each in this range. Iteration: ⍵
            ↑         ⍝ Take...
           ⍵          ⍝ ...⍵ elements...
             ⎕A       ⍝ ...from the alphabet
          ⌽           ⍝ Reverse
         ↑            ⍝ Pad with spaces...
  (1-2×⍵)             ⍝ ...(1 - 2*current iteration) elements
↑                     ⍝ Format
```

Comment: You have a stray `⌷`.

Comment: Also, I'd write `↑` instead of `⍪`.

Comment: Save two bytes: `↑{(1-2×⍵)↑⌽⍵↑⎕A}¨⌽⍳26`

Comment: That's clever :). Ty.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 64 bytes

```sh
printf '%s' {Z..A}|sed 'h;s/./ /g;G;s/ \n//;p;:a;s/ \b.//p;ta;Q'
```

Comment: I like this, but it seems to be missing the newline at the end.

Comment: I guess the requirements were a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 82 characters

```c
char*a="ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA\n",i=54;main(){while(i)printf("%*s",i-=2,a++);}
```

Works for any character coding, by embedding the full alphabet.  We print subsequent trailing substrings in a field twice as wide as required, to get the leading spaces.

I had hoped to be able to reduce it further with `while(printf());`, but couldn't arrange for the return value to reach zero at the right point.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
mṠ+ȯR' ←Lhṫ…"ZA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr//9t4bmgK8ivUicg4oaQTGjhuavigKYiWkH//w)

-5 thanks to [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb). Still a newb :p

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 38 bytes

```
25$* Z
{-2=`
$'
}T`L`_L`.$
;{:G`
 \w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy8hURUshiqta18g2gUtFnas2JMEnId4nQU@Fy7rayj2BSyGmnOv/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
25$* Z
```

Initialise the working string to 25 spaces and a single `Z`.

```
{-2=`
$'
}T`L`_L`.$
```

The usual approach for generating the alphabet: repeatedly duplicate the last letter, then decrement that letter with a transliteration, removing `A`s instead of decrementing them further. That means once we get to `A`, the second stage will delete the letter which was added by the first stage, so there won't be any net change and the loop stops. That gives us the first line of the output.

```
;{:G`
 \w
```

Now we really just repeatedly print the current line and the drop a space followed by a letter. The construction is slightly weird due to how loops and printing works in Retina. We need to print before we drop the letter, which requires a separate stage that otherwise doesn't do anything, and we also need to disable the implicit printing at the end of the program.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 206 bytes

```
public class Main{public static void main(String[]args){int i,j,k,l=90;for(k=26;k>=0;k--){for(i=k-1;i>0;i--){System.out.print(" ");}for(j=l;j>=65;j--){System.out.print((char)j);}l--;System.out.println();}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBCoMwFAWvElwlYIotVCifeIOuXJYuUrX2JzERE4Uinj2N0FXp6sHM8JRcJHdjZ1WrYxznh8GGNEZ6T64S7folPsiQZnHYkiFxWocJbX@7y6n3bEUbCOYq17kRlwKebqJanErQlShAc87WHaHQ/AhYFYA7qt8@dMPBzeEwprNAM5Ix2PZSCQOqEuUZ1N@SNi85MZVqwzn8amNpMtsW4wc)

Comment: I'm new so not familiar how to add a post, hope to help someone.!! :D

Comment: Also, the bytecount must be visible on the header.

Comment: its actually shorter to define an interface than class. also, the `args` array doesn't have to be called `args`, can be let's say `a` as well.

Comment: You can use `public class M` to save three bytes. And `String[]a` to save three more.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>87</s> 71 bytes

### Submission

```
{(0..25).map{(it..25).map{print(" ")
it}.map{print('Z'-it)}
println()}}
```

### Beautified

```
        {
            // For it from 25 to 0
            (0..25).map {
                // Print that number of spaces
                // Print the alphabet backwards from that letter
                (it..25).map { print(" ")
                it}.map { print('Z' - it) }
                // Newline
                println()
            }
        }
```

### Test

```
var f:()->Unit =
{(0..25).map{(it..25).map{print(" ")
it}.map{print('Z'-it)}
println()}}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    f()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 65 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=0To 25:?Spc(25-i);:For j=0To 25-i:?Chr(90-j-i);:Next:?:Next
```

#### Naïve Version, 68 Bytes

```vb
For i=0To 25:?Spc(25-i)Right("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA",26-i):Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 113 bytes

```
26
Count i while i-_ {
	Count b while b-25+i {
		Write 32
	}
	Count t while t-_+i {
		Write 90-t-i
	}
	Write 10
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9/IjMs5vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVM3XqGaixMimAQVTNI1MtXOBIlzhhdllqQqGBtxcdbCVJVAVZXoxqMosjTQLdHNBCuECBgacNX@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 74 bytes

That pesky `Chr$` function sure does like to add extra spaces

```
0ForI=0To25:?Tab(25-I);:ForJ=0To25-I:?Left$(Chr$(90-I-J),1);:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwC2/yNPWICTfyNTKPiQxScPIVNdT09oKKOwFEdb1tLL3SU0rUdFwzihS0bA00PXU9dLUMQQq8kutKPGysgfTnv//AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 100 bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the console

```vb
For I=0 To 25
For J=I To 25
Print" "
Next
For K=0 To 25-I
Print Left(Chr(90-I-K),1)
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/98tv0jB09ZAISRfwciUC8TzsvWE8gKKMvNKlBSUuPxSK0rAct4wlbqeEFkFn9S0Eg3njCINSwNdT11vTR1DTYhysLQ1mP3/f0gIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 79 bytes

Another BASIC answer for Ya.

```
For I=0To 25
For J=I To 25
?" ";
Next
For K=0To 25-I
?Chr$(90-I-K);
Next
?
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3y2/SMHT1iAkX8HIlAvE8bL1VIDw7JUUlKy5/FIrSsAS3lBVup5c9s4ZRSoalga6nrremlAl9mDq/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｚ［↔］Ｒ⇵
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNBJXVGRjNCJXUyMTk0JXVGRjNEJXVGRjMyJXUyMUY1,v=1)

Explanation (characters have been changed to their ASCII forms to look monospace):

```
Z       push the uppercase alphabet
 [ ]    map over prefixes
  ↔       reverse horizontally
    R   pad each line with the line number spaces
     ⇵  and reverse the whole thing vertically
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 113 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwEEX3niIMXczQElSwC1vpUUpIJ6agSZhUQcSzx4hv8XmLz0s@lXFKdd0j2G2NQTls8mVPb7Y@qurjsacpbzInsyBAp5pMer2nW1wYjYh5zcJPlswoJlwZrRfsT9Spv7T1X9GwA/1rtwc6Awyf4pCG8gU)

**Code, recursive function**

```
function f($s=0){echo ($s<26)?str_pad("", $s)
.implode(array_reverse(range(chr(65), chr(65+$s))))."
".f($s+1):"";}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($s=0){
  echo ($s<26)?           #it stops at the 26 letter
  str_pad("", $s)         #padding whitespace
  .implode(array_reverse(range(chr(65), chr(65+$s))))
                          #implode the range of letters,
                          #yes, range works with characters too
                          #reverse the array because it always starts with A  
  ."                      #concatenate a linebreak
   ".f($s+1):"";          #calling for the next letter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 127 Bytes

```
package main;import."strings";func main(){for i:=26;i>0;i--{print("\n",Repeat(" ",i-1));for j:=i;j>0;j--{print(string(j+64))}}}
```

This prints with a leading newline.

### Ungolfed and readable

```
package main
import . "strings"
func main(){
    for i := 26; i > 0; i-- {
        print("\n", Repeat(" ", i-1))
        for j := i; j > 0; j-- {
            print(string(j + 64))
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8///78gMTk7MT1VITcxM886M7cgv6hET6m4pCgzL71YyTqtNC8ZLKWhWZ2WX6SQaWVrZGadaWdgnamrW10AVFWioRSTp6QTlFqQmghkKyjpZOoaampag1RnWdlmWmcBFWfBFUNM1sjSNjPR1Kytrf3/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 82 bytes

```
	U =REVERSE(&UCASE)
O	OUTPUT =DUPL(' ',SIZE(U) - 1) U
	U LEN(1) REM . U	:S(O)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoAgEADQWb/ipjyhgqApcIi8IagU9RoamyOH/h9ze8v73nznZyxFMJhAJ4VI2PAyR9LSCcfJcwJj2W@oQLVxvQhZQweDBpZ1bXRgdaAdemAxRXRa0mFFKT8)

Finally got around to a SNOBOL answer for this challenge. Always prints with a trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC 3, <s>67</s> 64 bytes

*-3 bytes from @12Me21 using the `-I` trick*

Unfortunately the console is one character too narrow to fit the first line without wrapping the last character. Oh well.

```
FOR I=-25TO.?" "*-I+RIGHT$(@ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA,-I+1)NEXT
```

Comment: There's a neat trick you can do to avoid `STEP -1`. Make the loop go from `-25` to `0`, and use `-I` instead of `I`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>13</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
á*↔?[O╒v4
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a02a1d3f5b4fd57634&i=&a=1)

#### Unpacked (15 bytes) and explanation

```
VAr|]mc%Hv)
VAr                Uppercase alphabet, reversed
   |]              List of suffixes
     m             Map rest of program over array, printing each element with a linefeed:
      c              Copy top of stack
       %             Length
        Hv           Double and decrement
          )          Pad string on left with spaces to the specified length
```

<s>I think that [`VAr|]mc%Hv|z`](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VAr%7C]mc%25Hv%7Cz&i=&a=1) SHOULD work for 10 bytes (once packed), but what looks to me like a bug kills that solution.</s> I stupidly confused `|z` with `)` there. Thanks @recursive for pointing that out (and saving even another byte)!

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 87 bytes

```
fn main(){for i in 0..26{println!("{:>1$}",&"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"[i..],51-2*i)}}
```

### With Spaces and Indentation

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..26 {
        println!("{:>1$}", &"ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"[i..], 51-2*i)
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c96853bb26c883cc578e20dc29c2ab9e&version=stable)

Answer (score 1):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 156 bytes

```
a                         ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAi 0◀i 26a i➖25 ia➕i 25ai➕i 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f//w/z@xg/ze9uBeFnih/lTlijgAlGREeFhoSHBQYEB/n6@Pt5enh7ubq4uzk6OIG1A/esyFQyAzMZH0xsyFYzMIKbOaADSq4DCqxIVMh/Nm2ZkqpAJ5j2aNxWoyvTD/AlTEiFKgAaABQ2BzE4Q/v8fAA)

**Explanation:**

```
      start program
a                         ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA      big ol string
i 0            declare loop variable
    ◀i 26       loop 26 times
                  print concatenated string 
        a i➖25 i      number of spaces
        a➕i 25a      reverse alphabet minus last letter
        i➕i 1        increment loop variable
                   end loop
                  end program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), 118 bytes

```
var s="";for i in 0..<26{for _ in 0..<25-i{s+=" "};for j in 0..<26-i{s+="\(UnicodeScalar(90-i-j)!)"};s+="\n"};print(s)
```

**Prettyfied:**

```
var s = ""

for i in 0 ..< 26 {
    for _ in 0 ..< 25 - i {
        s += " "
    }

    for j in 0 ..< 26 - i {
        s += "\(UnicodeScalar(90 - i - j)!)"
    }
   
    s += "\n"
}  

print(s)
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/YFKDP93206)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 115 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(51)=SPACE(25)+'ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA'a:PRINT @
SET @=STUFF(@,len(@)/2,2,'')IF len(@)>0GOTO a
```

Shorter to just hard-code the initial string, then I used `STUFF()` to snip out two characters from the middle each loop.

I can save 3 bytes by using a `CHAR(51)` instead of a `VARCHAR(51)`, but that prints full-width trailing spaces for all rows, which don't appear to be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>133</s> 114 bytes

```cs
var S="";for(int I=26;I-->0;){var C='@';for(;C++<I+64;)S+=" ";for(;C>'@';)S+=C--;S+="\n";}System.Console.Write(S);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BC8IgGIbv@xXiZRNxRESXL0fgaYcg8NChOojZEDYFlUGM/XbL0Xt8ngdeHZn2wWQ9qhjRNfghqKlaKvRbTCpZjWZvX@iirGtiCtYN9ydSYYhka5Y8q4AkxxjePjTWJdTz/RF6xrodkKVYwetzvWkQlJ56ejwAkZRjhP@0K0FBgjEo5uEwrPITk5la4V30o2lvwSbTSAK5HK/Vmr8)

```cs
var S="";                   // Initialize the return string
for(int I=26;I-->0;){       // For all 26 rows (with I as the space count)
    var C='@';              // Initializing C with the char '@' which is one under 'A'
    for(;C++<I+64;)         // For all spaces needed and sets the char one up ('@' -> 'A', 'A' -> 'B')
        S+=" ";             // Add a space to the string
    for(;C>'@';)            // For all characters which are needed from the char countet above up down to 'A'
        S+=C;               // Add the char to the string
    S+="\n";                // Add a new line to the string
}
System.Console.Write(S);    // Output the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 22 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/'(1_')\0 25_|51$.Q.A
```

**Explanation:**

Generate two lists and reduce each until they are empty.

```
,/'(1_')\0 25_|51$.Q.A / the solution
                  .Q.A / A..Z
               51$     / pad to 51 chars
              |        / reverse it
         0 25_         / cut (_) at indices 0 and 25
   (   )\              / perform this along
    1_'                / drop (_) first from each (') list
,/'                    / flatten (,/) each (')
```

**Bonus:**

Another **22 byte** solution:

```
,/'(1_')\(25#$`;|.Q.A)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
2d*:&:1(?v:"@"+$1-48*}40.
l2(?vob1.>r~
-20.>~ao&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yhFy0rNylDDvsxKyUFJW8VQ18RCq9bEQI8rxwgomJ9kqGdXVMela2SgZ1eXmK9m@P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 14 bytes

```
26…v§&¦₵Av┅+†ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9nYWlh//8yNuKApnbCpybCpuKCtUF24pSFK@KAoOG5o///)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 58 bytes

Not the best answer for Ruby, but still good enough to get second place out of three entries lol. I just wanted to try a regex-based solution.

```ruby
s=' '*26+[*?A..?[].reverse*''
puts s while s.sub!(/ \S/){}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9hWXUFdy8hMO1rL3lFPzz46Vq8otSy1qDhVS12dq6C0pFihWKE8IzMnVaFYr7g0SVFDXyEmWF@zuvb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 18 bytes

```
R R*AZ@,\,26.sX,26
```

[Run it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Alternately, here's the equivalent 19-byte solution in an older version of Pip: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/KCwoTMsxykEnRsfITK84Akj@//9fNwcA)

#### Explanation

```
               ,26  Range(26)
             sX      String-multiply each element by space: list of 0 to 25 spaces
        \,26        Inclusive-range(1,26)
       ,             Range(each element)
      @              Use each range as an index into...
    AZ               Uppercase alphabet
            .       Concatenate those two lists itemwise
  R*                Reverse each string in the resulting list
R                   Reverse the list itself
                    Autoprint the list, one string per line (-l flag)
```

---

Another 18-byte answer using map:

```
RAZ@,1+_.sX_M R,26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/KMwxykHHUDterzgi3jcoTMfI7P///7o5AA) (19-byte equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 82 bytes

```lua
s=' 'for i=90,65,-1 do o=s:rep(i-65)for j=i,65,-1 do o=o..s.char(j)end print(o)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZdQT0tv0gh09bSQMfMVEfXUCElXyHfttiqKLVAI1PXzFQTJJ1lm4ksm6@nV6yXnJFYpJGlmZqXolBQlJlXopEPYv//DwA)

**Human readable code:**

```lua
s=' '
for i=90,65,-1 do
  o=s:rep(i-65)
  for j=i,65,-1 do
    o=o..s.char(j)
  end
  print(o)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), 23 bytes

```
e[{:[Eo{]x:}[{:D+o]lox]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwK1r7VUS7acR5P4LLd24l7d1nHGdud641FZSIQspiTBkKBlT5p@9dwu@BBBQiIYPz3TxiaB3d8@sQCWwbWYcv/pyyD87HgBDwWJrqMu8aiYtiYh94hwPEayVy5jQfI4pL4N/6Qv8C/474K10gcipGM2ouO/Wq2xS6OI7Ic0GtPX@Pt2i8DPysrKqYABXRKyCycSLIwIUCGXNHToyGURDJADbTYhluX4jrCsdsTcSWe7JV/gz6qkISfmZPKXOHgjkgMG5HyoPqfwrK8@GimP5jz2QkZmDBhQ2/EvCLtkIWgNf6URGU8pyIp8vy8zDmGI5XGbAd0fqRuxAu53TsDsnuMTmwqaP3YmxOfSBDAdmG04ERXiut3ZzocU6MMAC6cD@fkMRNnunG9v97aGyqQJD4nVJRYBpsyPPRZSwdolUiVGGmZoryh2BTJV35wjy27laRmHapkNGgTMt9s8tNsJ4U4nH85AZ3WSg5fMtfoTRSdKjTNizCcBGEEwm1wzUbIPdVFV11Y2omqjs6kTkZnjuiQSHHyAwm9iysgIDP4XEyTgkSMc7pc8bjZ1XGa5nAcREP34SaHIyBgdAh0WSQUcmYcqARxhpW@qXjpOHKoot3wOkec6Y4gSsG0ujH6E4IEq7uq7OJoSmDgCjoJLaNI8eQQGMMBKBkif6eLogrdULYrvi9QvqRszwifziEFOGi74PuWBvy5lgm4jB3UWCzLiQkCqAs5LxbKScXXSOX7EQtHuJ0PqBTRCgDNU/oslnwOoCg92ldm5xIIHWeIsJ5qcrBpmIRNx6Bc8rxqJ6ZACMGSTxG4JTa0KeFAU/h5g9jONnUIYI6Bs8cgxRUxY2cPUJNmfKr7sKRlATNIVTbqiWaqcKyjBWp490s0eVWcXfK6IfS1KXVAbwJjsbksiJQQTGTt6uftNxa2SHnX0SumnJjzB9ThiWpHlm7JTFfhkIzo5LektSMpl/oWY6h02eVemm7oavGzPWRRCM3ZhwZXU5ApBcIUgLuiDtMvrRidnNYod104elvkJ5gVqYYNPLKg7lJpDfQkLo8s@xFwwxTpYHGTLGSQf7nm4QlUrBVx8SjUCmLVCepf0q4VEZVRvQLaUUdJHqjgHi6mVZC0DywRBdztfSVZdZV46UU8@c8NMMZ0q2CKDYSMG4B0hFlGSkZoZFlUT53LOECZliOqnZCNxlpy@XIa1lVpNn4Uxq7ftgDxZzunPxuYoDquAMKWPE@vJp97Uwj3I6TVkLI/Q8AIiwRewfQnkngnLQNjSbATXZEJ2JqByn3pst/p2THYwbHZbrTMO8YSbGwjtUXzRJTHkrYm9OcZQAy7Uxnwz2Rxv4NDI5TNi85lPeCyCWKTDo81xJIE5uC9CnpYlJbYsj0JdbKUmTACAIQpbr9TJUmx5JbnymZ1/3D4/4B@HV9uf4Nc363zo8qvh53SnluQwso/JKMmOmLs8GhTJFVNVlvbIEUCSo@XfSeIrsM/L3B2ZNwtviokuvFZNltu5SOpcQ3ZYTgjpGGVvttDpKg9WiVx0dyAn7qrF65K809eEVEFrxcK6X80BFb/eMie3ZUDuiTm5JwbknpqTe2pA7pk5uWcG5J6bk3tuQO47c3LfGZB7YU7uhQG5l@bkXhqQe2VO7pUBObeBG5uExa8N6Jl4HmsQFybGPWgQGCaBZjeIDBPzvmngyyaxMW3gLibe/FMTfzFxmF8aETSh@HFlm6y@YeOQYZ1gSjx7hBVgzyRjf0I2h/4N2KybsAmRjVzuTuTBro4Pna/A@gpWgjEZhPsPB/cb8hS5PeoSCij1FlogodNpVRdsKUCy2kPdNKVhreBrf64tdQz1WFdbDBtV1WUp5KlXTTmzvjXsLCOkVFTruLuqauSI4q42wD0dL5yVL8S@jn6wZ9t37AA6l12nBn7aQ3yn8QhvHMQDgOyZgPwWQR7FrnAC9/oBQH5rAnIzSSyCXYD32M6lE@l2mHcPdnPTBO3XUqXcjl3@ABi/NoH4B0I8uAq4vyhR37HVjcweyQD6EN4EYZU5XiBuTGDjl/4aAYM27XR0SXrfETMHtrYNstI/CPrt8dmtYv7HRF3fyHz49s0D2PMbE3x/I77jkweA97cJPAvh/f4g@P4AfBrvO9Vu4ivAKQIP5Jk7n59j7y0tFYp3CEDAQD0jLZd9cy4jEy57kkt2PWMmjHp/YCbNvp7PfgM@RvJ0kU96lr/gUEbhkB361xLeRsJ2jNem8uweROGTJRy@NPPQm4ysoP63inp@9WYKPLuNM0WVjae3MKEijYfSePxSVT/GR0JEyzK5CPsiY2TYJAkDfEc5vpKi5T1cevBZj6@pzo3xBTX6I77s8Yn0fuHx2BemOzh/voPrd5OpS/Zwxja6HTu9q7HTI9LDcl@4oT98L5Nl0r6VNkr0e1tPXpj6Xd7r1YZ9ZvlcoWMA4Kt8jZvfsdYmbc1ZRnoLa8LyX8gymtFAGlrMOHEE8yLC/Rsn8zvP@CMD@U6kTbnIFikxDRm7XxnHd66I8U1Upr3PqejxFPU45j6um36uTHCXhHB0/36CMRYJFGkd/6FGEXZRFmOxA6RNBMhmbW3jPXd8yc7vzBNZfvCF7QyLk94Y0xwkk0LqK1zppbPrT/SaKAfBG6jDSdUBZZ8gQMRxMOWnua/d052PK0J10xSttEMoci0WC6Akk3cH5NnLtMMV/94ZkOcvFs9TThyBxblEgrf4cjqArpf7sCj3vCcu0UB7/d7k7qtiv/piqQFyq17sK1n@OkAktOtL9qV@V6H9e5G2SWFtsqhXuMTI5Te/d6ol6ZuWIbKBJ4nmZifpkAxskzzzW4rzYiHOYk65SnLKVSWntOrcQO1yum0xNWcCh5vHBo7G5VGL7M3ATvC909eHh2nHY53XzVsRKm3IC9sRSqJU@5e1lxH4I4e0x1P1GqjThbC2B2trBpY@XiiqSRA8vLR58DUR2leFTjPo4zVw0bgNxHy7WMzHalyNYecCa@L5NfdFyF3yo8tn9QrZQYX8yqII6mh61zcgqL4d2ihxbekpMRNVN2032kVd/AfMI9vZ70cdu49XHQN5pfMhBre@B0UMBo9WE2v/WwNN7DMxY8x/DFtL1BdWl2P83@N1oB/Qgc5Y6Dm4MWvdTlLEr7/YlSNMastVBAD50JZtwdQl72MvqEnsUuuo136tPqotCLWI3iOinwEFVnMzKKyjJj0Oav9MPbefc274eWIzdj2V3boBu3Nk919se@3JntlqD3ZV3UnN@xUWvUs3WMpOqbc1rLHQIqlyoYp947XNtFpphyVpYUm@K1l371RUE096vbyrp/Q9nlmn0JkhzeQLPkmzpe5cku9VpBRByOSBTJR/uoqfR6btUNXueX1vtL5hfvUMP3VxBJSGEzKbMh@2@BwYhzKqhAM2BbYT2L3bNf3Rzfqt1E9acjTHyFr2EMhzZUe0zJN5pQkrBVfqVFg9klco2Qec5Q83jVIguxqzQJBf2PWIQ@LBXpswjANR@g6qms3TiQfyH0jbaMiSOKun3GPJh68z5gsyC7l/0cWTYD4D4xDgxFW4SSm9cnBycnyyTXTTS3evyYT80@4NSNceFRaAKx/CF0RIvgM4TB03/ZSh1XTjMB@rhAD4mGaHsfSe9wZHlXSwtArRYMTQ12OsblZp3Z5tAXF9gM5p0ypZLblUn1VyS8RuLHK9uM1FXSgm/nz@Pw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 41 bytes

```sh
eval 1={A..Z}'$1;<<<${(l:#1-65:)}$1;'|tac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxR8HQttpRTy@qVl3F0NrGxkalWiPHStlQ18zUSrMWKKReU5KY/P8/AA)

Explanation:

- `1={A..Z}'$1;<<<${(l:#1-65:)}$1;'`: construct the string `1=A$1;<<<${(l:#1-65:)}$1; 1=B...1; 1=C...1; ... 1=Z...1;` (with every letter from `A` to `Z` in place of the `{A..Z}` in each case)
- `eval`uate that string as `zsh` code:

  - `1=A$1`: prepend `A` (or which ever letter is in that repetition) to the variable `$1`
  - `${(l:#1-65:)}`: generate `#1-65` spaces:

    - `#1`: Take the ASCII character code of the first character of `$1`
    - subtract `65`. The first iteration will have `A` as the first character of `$1`, the character code of which is `65`, and since `65-65=0`, no spaces will be printed. Then for further letters, another space will be added each time.
  - `$1`: and append the variable `$1`
  - `<<<`: and print that with a newline
- `|tac` and reverse the output line-wise

---

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 36 bytes

```sh
eval 2={A..Z}'$2;<<<$1$2;1+=\ ;'|tac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxR8HIttpRTy@qVl3FyNrGxkbFEEgbatvGKFir15QkJv//DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```elixir
import Enum
map 25..0,&(IO.puts List.duplicate(' ',&1)++reverse(slice ?A..?Z,0..&1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/M7cgv6hEwTWvNJcrN7FAwchUT89AR03D01@voLSkWMEns7hEL6W0ICczObEkVUNdQV1HzVBTW7sotSy1qDhVoxgokapg76inZx@lY6CnB5TU/P8fAA)

Still want to find a way around that `List.duplicate` call....

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 54 bytes

```forth
: f for i spaces i for i 65 + emit next cr next ;
25 f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVE9b8MgFNz5FTe2Sl21lZyh3jN3jz0gAoEIgwW4bn@9@8B26qos7@vu3tOhfEi6uqoc5vkdCpTCIA5cyEjJUh5rHCB7k@DkV4IIS2zYWw01P7BMPMOhqtChxUcwjqCHV1jjSMYrRMmD0NZcdXpmKLLra2G9H6CC70khebzAOGHHaD4lzqZjGXS/KOOHIr@11vldca9n/unduobh72tpjlN24AlJS6qcDL2PaRESfszbIrid@Dd5svL3rmw3cQjNAybtoyyp8BeZuTdCHuvCLM5tm6W7LPvKrjIXYXfZJuvklK1kK73Z0f2YNnr@jV/qGDWowwkjuLVQ7HH@AQ)

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( n -- ) \ Print n+1 lines of searchlight.
  for        \ loop from n to 0 inclusive [i]
    i spaces   \ print i spaces
    i for      \ loop from i to 0 inclusive [j];
               \ in Forth, the innermost loop count is always i
      i 65 + emit \ print a char whose charcode is j + 65
    next       \ end inner loop
    cr         \ print a newline
  next ;     \ end outer loop
25 f       \ push 25 and call f
```

Just started fiddling with Forth. Unlike the [golfing tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68448/78410) says, it looks like `n for .. next` loop is the shortest for simple decreasing loops and `n1 n0 do .. loop` for increasing loops. The recursive call word `recurse` or `recursive` is way too verbose, and it still costs at least an `if .. then`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
₂F₂N-D<ð×?Aus£R,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOTGxD76brYHN5weLq9Y2nxocVBOv//AwA)

```
₂F                # for N in [0, 1, 2, ..., 25]:
  ₂N-D<ð×?        # print 25 - N spaces with no trailing newline
          Aus£R,  # print the first 26 - N letters of the uppercase alphabet, reversed
                  # (implicit) exit for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 21 bytes

```
=_r1GV26
+*\ -25NG=tG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3za@yNA9zMiMS1srRkHXyNTP3bbE/f9/AA)

Basically, it sets G to `ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`, and next prints space repeated some amount of times and G, then removes the first letter of G.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 101 bytes

```
X's26
while X
O's""
let Y be X
while Y
cast Y+64 into L
let O be+L
let Y be-1

let X be-1
say " "*X+O
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 66 bytes

```
=LET(r,26-ROW(1:26),x,CONCAT(CHAR(65+r)),REPT(" ",r)&RIGHT(x,r+1))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](http://=LET(r,26-ROW(1:26),x,CONCAT(CHAR(65+r)),REPT(%22%20%22,r)&RIGHT(x,r+1)))

Answer (score 0):

## [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 253 bytes

```
Z{\A\
}H{\C\BZ}A{\M\L\K\JG{\I\HD}D{\G\F\E\DH}D}E{\V\U\TB{\S\R\Q\PF{\O\NA}F}B}S{\ }T{SS}U{TT}V{UU}W{VV}WVS\Z\Y\X\WEWV\Y\X\WESTUW\X\WETUW\WESUWEUW\U\TBSTW\TBTWBSW\R\Q\PFW\Q\PFSTUV\PFTUVFSUV\NAUVASTV\L\K\JGTV\K\JGSV\JGVGSTU\HDTUDSU\F\E\DHU\E\DHST\DHTHS\BZZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbctowEH33V@z4KWlLBjPTzjQTOgMFQm/pRb60sDy42Amags3IStKMRt9OV2DAXAy9pHqQtdZq95zjXXn6IEdpUptNRXoDdRC2bc96Chto6a7C19js6YbCD/ge3@HbS4VvsNvSLYWX2ME2trq6pdsKffTQbSpk@AU/46eOwo941dAd3dRMIWhXMaY95braV56nA@X7OvAZ9vAbfsWgHfj5grleMF@YJ5le0KaFCc7cgGY3aLIgTxLMZzrh04PmDqPVVcPzG8z1c8C0MA/m0@Rfki/Bd70W83L43nxmLk1ulxHb3owUsCw@maZCQvaQWTQm8YS06dv2AJ5A7YVl3Y/4OIZxnJwY3U7hFVTPLaDBryEV0fxtvzqgjTq8eA5hEm2@vqjDy/yEGXcUvWqtTE5mbWVFZDkrKyHLAFz5Xm/AcNZB8915TmcAdTqn7M1tMxZUojWF7UExOFyss@z3WmJL4OkiJR9YpY5LWHwBC9EuD7oUhFNg57DXbwMtA3zINx5n8fGIU8ETCXZbiFQ8g9tkEsrhiCc38F2Ewx@xzIAnIEfxPKUIJ2f20ZBUg2fxTy5PTq1ybFuKqmOCFsqUQwWc/aW63Noq17JhKjU6@pn@RsiVevecrqtbCSFk0zF5xIIEjfgwlKn4T1rqI1ouWFdKWB9m@4jlcoRaeQvR5dbfuJwqVAcD0xn984qz2xR3G/fRpmROuWSPQHUPRUp8Z1JuVWf@Nyuhlje8c74mt/uZ8hCLSsg910Sre26uw1exAZ/JiIr37F5wGZ/kgp0exFDULEyATk@p@nmSSXE7lDxNCh0xHIUkpWkJmeaeWyLuEbBIs1ZGs3id/FtjbiHYyaRLM/1RxeykKSpbpGxqYPYL)

Link is to a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

## Vyxal, <s>704</s> 24 bytes

[Try it online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%82%84%CA%80%C6%9B%3A%CA%81%E1%B9%98%C6%9B65%2BC%3B%E1%B9%85%24%C3%B0*%24%2B%3B%E1%B9%98&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
₄ʀƛ:ʁṘƛ65+C;ṅ$ð*$+;Ṙ
```

Behind door number 3, we have this answer - again just prints out the string (Edit 1: never mind, it doesn't)

Comment: [23 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%84%CA%81%C6%9B%3A%CA%80%C6%9B1%7C65%2BC%3B%E1%B9%85%24%5C%20*%24%2B%3B%E1%B9%98%E2%81%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224897/78850)

Comment: rip - might as well put the 23 byter

Comment: @Ausername the 23 byter prints everything in reverse.

Comment: [Try it Online! For 20](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%E2%82%84%CA%80%C6%9B%3A%CA%81%E1%B9%98%C6%9B65%2BC%3B%E1%B9%85%24%C3%B0*%24%2B%3B%E1%B9%98&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 1431 bytes

```
    ^         ^
   / \       / \
  /set\     /do \
 ^-----^   ^-----^
/a\   / \ /a\   /[\
---  /26 \---  ^---^
     -----    ^-   -^
             ^-     -^
            /]\      -^
           ^---^      -^
          ^-   -^      -^
         ^-     -^      -^
        ^-       -^      -^
       /[\       / \     /[\
      ^---^     /set\   ^---^
     ^-   -^   ^-----^  -^  -^
    ^-     -^ /c\   /a\ / \  -^
   / \     / \---   ---/set\  -^
  /set\   /do \       ^-----^  -^
 ^-----^ ^-----^     /a\   /-\  -^
/b\   /a\-^   /[\    ---  ^---^  -^
---   ---/b\ ^---^       /a\ /1\  -^
         ---/ \  -^      --- ---  /[\
           /set\  -^             ^---^
          ^-----^  -^           ^-  / \
         /b\   /+\ /?\         / \ /out\
         ---  ^---^---^       /do \-----^
             / \ /b\ / \     ^-----^    -^
            /-1 \---/out\   /c\   /[\   / \
            -----  ^-----   ---  ^---^ /chr\
                  / \           ^-  / \-----^
                 /chr\         ^-  /out\   / \
                ^-----        / \  -----^ /10 \
               / \           /set\     / \-----
              /32 \         ^-----^   /chr\
              -----        /c\   /-\  -----^
                           ---  ^---^     /+\
                               /c\ /1\   ^---^
                               --- ---  /c\ / \
                                        ---/65 \
                                           -----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTBbsIwDL3nK3JHkVemcd2HzIsEoRI7ICZgh319lzh2EicFaZWoEvvZfn52@f697s9fR3cLp/k8L4uNj7fyeBNfYJGv8RQNcJvv2QLHS7J4l54UxScDe@RAPn2giY542O4s0skTkNJQEJVLb7EWDi6DtBk@mZS2eybSOzjz6CnZBxd71nyxnaqIWEzPQHRqOq00imb5ZzQXCKRa1I4KODUHYAWTblyDAFKPptLo4aSEXOq8rMzH5SRw4Lrk5TbruAhTa0dwo3emO6HWN@FyC@WeE1bFWrGc72bvujE2qqkZ5tWUZLmNTeTzjtWa1vHyc0fFjou0fST9eJEVG0pwwDKIRsd@O91EKahcugcseiqmdfu9fAWN3BBOVw3WW6faX2NM4JREg4WVHZMXGrUQdwnTy4jXTJp/BubT4eF1a3Gc5mqjmkioa/qgT7sy1Ry7wWdoSU@rO2zcwwJ5iQOuqvgkEHZv/wgQHZblDw)

Yes, I wrote this all by hand. It's kinda therapeutic...

Answer (score 0):

## C89, 96 bytes

```c
i,j;main(){for(;i<26;)++j>25?puts("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA"+i),j=++i:putchar(' ');return 0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6NzEzT0OzOi2/SMM608bIzFpTWzvLzsjUvqC0pFhDKSoyIjwsNCQ4KDDA38/Xx9vL08PdzdXF2clRSTtTUyfLVls70wqoNDkjsUhDXUFd07ootaS0KE/BwLqW6///f8lpOYnpxf91i0tSbJMtLP/rFqSmJOaVZCb/1w1PzMkBAA)

```c
int i, j;

int main()
{
    while(i<26){
        extern int puts();
        extern int putchar();
        
        if (++j > 25) {     
            puts("ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA" + i);
            j = ++i;
        }
        else { 
            putchar(' ');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 25 bytes

```
;⍥(-1&p⊂↯∶@ -1,⇌+@A⇡.).26
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=O-KNpSgtMSZw4oqC4oav4oi2QCAtMSzih4wrQEHih6EuKS4yNg==)

**Explanation:**

```
                       .26   # Put 26 onto the stack twice
 ⍥(                   )     # Repeat 26 times
                     .       # Copy the counter value
                    ⇡        # Make an array of natural numbers less than counter
                 +@A         # Add "A" to each element, getting ["A", "B",...]
                ⇌            # Reverse
             -1,             # Copy counter and subtract 1
         ↯∶@                 # Make an array of space chars
        ⊂                    # Join spaces with the letters
      &p                     # Print the result
    -1                       # Subtract 1 from the original counter
;                            # Pop the counter from the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 7 bytes

```
kZ€ƛd«Ḣ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwia1rigqzGm2TCq+G4oiIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

```
kZ€ƛd«Ḣ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
kZ€      # ‎⁡suffixes of uppercase reversed alphabet
   ƛd«Ḣ  # ‎⁢prepend spaces to make each double their length then remove the first space
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).